# "Cowsay" in short

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Simulate `cowsay` in the default mode.

```
$ cowsay <<< Hello
 _______
< Hello >
 -------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

$ perl -e 'print "Long text "x20' | cowsay
 __________________________________________
/ Long text Long text Long text Long text  \
| Long text Long text Long text Long text  |
| Long text Long text Long text Long text  |
| Long text Long text Long text Long text  |
\ Long text Long text Long text Long text  /
 ------------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

How short can be the code? The cow and the balloon can be slightly different, but all elements should be present. Dynamic/multiline balloon is a plus.

Explicit list of the required elements:

- Text;
- Balloon;
- Line from the cow to the balloon;
- The cow (eye[s], month, ears, body, legs (minimum two), udder, tail).

`/usr/share/cowsay/cows/` may be accessed, but obviously not `/usr/games/cowsay` itself.

Note: here is the `/usr/share/cowsay/cows/default.cow` file:

```
$the_cow = <<"EOC";
        $thoughts   ^__^
         $thoughts  ($eyes)\\_______
            (__)\\       )\\/\\
             $tongue ||----w |
                ||     ||
EOC
```

Usage of the file is optional. When used, it must be accessed by full path. (Windows users may copy it to something like `C:\usr\share\cowsay\co\default.cow`, for fairness).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because the specification for the format is extremely non-descriptive, which makes it impossible to determine validity of outputs.

Answer (score 29):

### Mathematica: Work in progress

I'll pin down the balloon once I can get the cow to settle:

```
ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]
```

[image]

Comment: ...is it done yet?

Comment: Any further development on that balloon?

Answer (score 16):

## Perl, 84 characters

```
print$a='-'x52,<>=~s/.{1,50}\b/sprintf"
|%-50s|",$&/rge,"$a
\\   
]:p
| )=
| P= 
 ¬"
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text |
|Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text |
|Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text |
|Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text |
----------------------------------------------------
\   
]:p
| )=
| P= 
 ¬
```

Admittedly, I golfed the cow as much as I golfed the code.  But the Mathematica cow is going to win anyway :)

**Note:** Requires Perl 5.16 for the `/r` non-destructive substitution flag.

Comment: Can you tell us please what is that `r` after the `s///`? Can not find such flag in the documentation. Thank you.

Comment: Upvoted. Not everyone is brave enough to call that "a cow"

Comment: Bow your head left to see the cow.

Comment: @manatwork the `r` flag returns the result, instead of modifying the operand in place (`<>` is of course read-only, and can't be modified).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Vi. @belisarius, it gets a [dachshund](http://davidslonim.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/long-dog-web.jpg) look here because the `line-height: 1.4em` set for the code blocks, but in terminal it looks better.

Comment: @manatwork I've got it! :D

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby: <s>152</s> <s>150</s> <s>149</s> <s>146</s> 143 characters

```ruby
load'/usr/share/cowsay/cows/default.cow'
p=%w{U~ o* o o}
puts l=?-*44,gets.gsub(/(.{1,40})\b\s*/){"( %-41s)\n"%$1}+l,$the_cow.gsub(/\$\w+/){p.pop}
```

The cow art is read from the default.cow file and decorated in after-12-rounds-vs-Mike-Tyson manner, similar with a `cowthink -e 'o*' -T 'U~'` invocation.

The text is read from standard input and wrapped at most 40 characters. Line breaks in the input text are not supported.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ perl -e 'print "Long text "x15' | ruby cow.rb 
--------------------------------------------
( Long text Long text Long text Long text  )
( Long text Long text Long text Long text  )
( Long text Long text Long text Long text  )
( Long text Long text Long text            )
--------------------------------------------
        o   ^__^
         o  (o*)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
             U~ ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

### With art bending: <s>138</s> <s>135</s> 136 characters

```ruby
load'/usr/share/cowsay/cows/default.cow'
puts l=?-*44,gets.gsub(/(.{1,40})\b\s*/){"( %-41s)\n"%$1}+l,$the_cow.gsub(/\$.+?([use]+)\b/,'\1')
```

As the elements have to be just present, we can use what we have in place instead of defining realistic ones.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby cow.rb <<< 'Hello poor little cow'
--------------------------------------------
( Hello poor little cow                    )
--------------------------------------------
        s   ^__^
         s  (es)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
             ue ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL <s>133 140 138</s> 122

This one liner takes screen input in the form of a character vector or array enclosed in quotes via: ←⍎⍞ The appearance of the output is improved by including leading and following spaces in the input.

```
('∘'⍪'∘',((¯2↑1,⍴t)⍴t←⍎⍞),'∘')⍪'∘'⋄5 19⍴(,⍉(19⍴2)⊤323584 196592 63503 4072 3096)\'∘^__^∘(oo)\_______(__)\)\/\||----w|||||'
```

The cow character locations on each row of the array are specified as 19 bit boolean vectors.

To use input the one liner followed by the bubble text in quotes:

```
' Hello '

°°°°°°°°°
° Hello °
°°°°°°°°°
°  ^__^
 ° (oo)\_______
   (__)\       )\/\
       ||----w |
       ||     ||
```

Multi-line text is input as an array.

```
3 36⍴' Multi-line text input as an array. '

°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
° Multi-line text input as an array. °
° Multi-line text input as an array. °
° Multi-line text input as an array. °
°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
°  ^__^
 ° (oo)\_______
   (__)\       )\/\
       ||----w |
       ||     ||
```

This version can be tested via the free APL interpreter at www.nars2000.org

Comment: How to properly count the characters? I counted 171 UTF-8 bytes and 141 Unicode codepoints here (newlines included). /* Also haven't found what I need to `apt-get install` to run APL... */

Comment: @Vi. The APL+WIN v5 character set is based on single byte characters. I have to convert them to UTF-8 to get them to render properly on this site. Therefore I believe I am justified in counting characters including newline characters as single bytes. I am not sure how you can run APL. I normally recommend the free version at http://www.nars2000.org but it does not appear to support relative assign.

Answer (score 2):

### K, 178

```
{-1'g,({"+ ",x,((&/(c-4;60-#x))#" ")," +"}'l),(g:,(&/(64;4+c::#*l:(60*!-_-(#x)%60)_x))#"+"),("+  ^__^";" + (oo)\\_______";"   (__)\\       )\\/\\";"       ||----w |";"       ||     ||");}
```

.

```
k){-1'g,({"+ ",x,((c-#x)#" ")," +"}'l),(g:,(&/(64;4+c::#*l:(60*!-_-(#x)%60)_x))#"+"),("+  ^__^";" + (oo)\\_______";"   (__)\\       )\\/\\";"       ||----w |";"       ||     ||");}"Hello codegolf.stackexchange.com"
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Hello codegolf.stackexchange.com +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  ^__^
 + (oo)\_______
   (__)\       )\/\
       ||----w |
       ||     ||
```