# minigolf - display anything 3d

Tags: code-golf

The goal is to write the smallest program in any language which displays any three dimensional output. It might be graphics, it might be ASCII art, but any reasonable person should immediately and unambiguously recognize it as "something 3d".

Opening external files or other resources is not allowed. All output has to be generated by your program.

The shortest code with a score higher than 1 wins.

Comment: Where are you going to find a reasonable person? This isn't objective enough to be called a spec.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : this is why I added the condition "score higher than 1", assuming that there are at least some reasonable persons reading and voting the answers.

Comment: @vsz, there are so many trivial answers to this question that you are probably better off making it a pure popularity contest.

Comment: @dan1111, or closing it as "not a constructive question".

Comment: FWIW, there was an attempt in the sandbox (which might still be ongoing) to define a *good* [3D drawing question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/603/194)

Comment: from the CowSay question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11252/5011  (not mine, so not taking credit)

Comment: I agree with @dan1111. I vote to reopen, on the condition that the challenge is changed to a popularity contest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### HTML, 1 character

```
❒
```

This will appear as:

❒

There are several other characters that look three dimensional (at least to me) if you don't like that one:

## ❒ ❍ ✰ ✞ ➫ ➮ ➪ ♨ ✐ ✏

Answer (score 18):

### QBASIC 211 bytes

```
SCREEN 13
WINDOW(-160,-100)-(159,99)
FOR x=0TO 63
 PALETTE x,x*65793
NEXT
FOR i=16TO-16STEP-.1
 FOR j=16TO-16STEP-.05
  s=SQR(i*i/2+j*j/2)
  PSET(i*10,j*5+17.32*COS(s)),18.2*(COS(s)-SIN(s)*j/s)+31+RND
 NEXT
NEXT
```

The color for each pixel is chosen by adding the *z* value on the curve with the partial derivative with respect to *y*, generating a 'fake' lighting effect. The added random value helps to smooth the borders between regions. Produces something similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: That's a blast from the past.

Answer (score 7):

### PHP, 23 characters

```
<?=" __\n/_/|\n|_|/\n";
```

Outputs:

```
 __
/_/|
|_|/
```

Comment: Why not do it in GolfScript? You can use newline for one char rather than two inside `'`

Answer (score 7):

### Logo, 31 characters

My [Logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29) is a bit rusty, but this should draw a torus:

```
repeat 180[rt 2 circle 45 fw 3]
```

[image: Torus]

Run it online: http://logo.twentygototen.org/9NxYy2Pw.

Answer (score 6):

### Lua, 12 characters

```
print'(.Y.)'
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 11 characters

```
print'()))'
```

Prints:

```
()))
```

It's <strike>a [tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29)</strike> an overturned [barrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel).

Comment: +1 for linking to the Wikipedia page for cylinders, because the concept of tube definitely needed more explanation :D

Comment: Overturned barrel?

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica 19

```
Graphics3D@Cuboid[]
```

[image: 3D]

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 7 characters

```
print A
```

Prints a road (which has a line painted across it) receding into the distance.

Comment: ...looks more like the letter `A` to me `:P`

Comment: @Volatility, then according to my working definition of reasonable, you aren't reasonable :)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 337 bytes

```
from pygame import*
from math import*
init();d=display;s=d.set_mode((640,480));a=0
def R(x,y,z,a):c,s=cos(a),sin(a);y,z=y*c-z*s,y*s+z*c;z,x=x*s-z*c-8,z*s+x*c;f=1e3/z;return-f*x+320,f*y+240
while s.fill(time.wait(5)):event.get();t=[R(x,y,z,a)for x in-1,1for y in-1,1for z in-1,1];[draw.line(s,-1,i,j)for i in t for j in t];a+=.01;d.flip()
```

A basic cube spinner.

Comment: Put `R` on one line, replace the nested `for` loop with `[draw.line(s,-1,i,j)for i in t for j in t]` and then put the whole `while` loop on a single line. That'll save you quite a few bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### R - 73 characters

Way longer than the previous answer but i like it:

```
t=seq(0,2*pi,.01);r=1e3:1;plot(r%o%cos(t),r%o%sin(t),col=grey(1:1e3/1e3))
```

[image]

Basically draw a thousand circles of decreasing radius and shade of grey.
Because of the default aspect ratio the result is more an ellipsoid than a sphere however.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 0 characters

Output:

```
>>>
```

Which can only reasonably be interpreted as some sort of angled surface :). I prefer to think of it as a jagged, concave cliff face.

Comment: To me seems like the first step of a [paper folding](http://203.160.252.19/~ftp_sys/YOCA/DT-880-A3%20size.jpg) diagram…

Comment: LOL !!! 0 Charachters solution !! :D