# Generate a Stack Exchange Favicon

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Do you recognize the PPCG logo?
it looks like this, when you do an ascii art of it.

```
+---+
|PCG|
+---+
   v
```

Now, In this Code Golf, You will make a code, that makes logos for other sites, similar to the PPCG logo.

## What You should do

The "Shortened" string will be the string, with all upper case letters and numbers in the input string.(Which would be `PPCG` when the input string is `Programming Puzzles & Code Golf`)

The "Box" (

```
+---+
|   |
+---+
   v
```

)
should fit the Shortened string perfectly.(No bigger or smaller)

Also the `v` part should be exactly 1 down and 1 left to the down right `+`.

Then output the box which has the shortened string in it.

## Example

`Stack Overflow`:

```
+--+
|SO|
+--+
  v
```

`Area 51`:

```
+---+
|A51|
+---+
   v
```

## Rules

You may assume that the input contains at least one digit or upper case letter.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57845/8478) [Also related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73296/8478)

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes, Very closely related, but not duplicate.

Comment: Also, This is Highly inspired by PPCG itself.

Comment: Can you clarify what the text inside should be? For example, what if the name of the site was `99 bottles of beer`. Would that be `99BOB`? Does the box get bigger to compensate for that? Is there a maximum box size, or site name size? What kind of characters might appear in the site title?

Comment: @MatthewRoh The purpose of the links is so that the challenges show up in the sidebar, it's not a dupe vote. That said, I personally think removing the unwanted characters and also printing the `^` doesn't add much compared to the second challenge I linked, but I won't cast a dupe hammer on that but let the communitz decide whether they consider it a dupe or not.

Comment: Unlimited Box and Site name size. Also, if it was `99 bottles of beer`, It would be `99`.

Comment: @MartinEnder The related ones you linked have a whitespace front and behind the string. mine don't.

Comment: @MatthewRoh The actually seems like the most minor difference which isn't going to require any substantial changes to any of the existing solutions. The best case for this challenge is the acronymisation and the `v`.

Comment: [Also related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11249/194)

Comment: Why does `99 bottles of beer` become `99` and not `99BOB`? Is everything after a number excluded?

Comment: Because It is numbers and uppercase, not numbers and first character.

Comment: If it was `99 Bottles Of Beer`, it would be `99BOB`.

Comment: Oh okay, I missed that part :p.

Comment: @MatthewRoh That would be a useful test case to add.

Comment: What about uppercase letters inside the string? i.e. would `99 bOttles Of Beer` turn into `99OOB`?

Comment: Yes. Every uppercase letters.

Comment: THERE IS NO BF ANSWER SO I AM GIVING AWAY TO MY FAVORITE

Comment: NOOOOO @MattherRoh, I have been working on it :( I am so close. I even created an assember to convert "readable" code to BF :(((

Comment: @Rohan :O Im really impressed

Comment: @MatthewRoh if I manage to get close I'lll still post it

Comment: @MatthewRoh its still buggy,  let me see if i can get a bf answer after all

Comment: @MatthewRoh heres what I have so far. https://sange.fi/esoteric/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html

Comment: Just cant figure out how to stirip uppercase characters in brainf***

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Check all uppercase. That would be simple I think.

Comment: @MattheyRoh yeah I think I may have an interesting solution

Comment: @Matthew I can just check if it is less than 96 :D

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64763/make-the-ppcg-favicon/)

Answer (score 24):

## Vim, 42 strokes

```
:s/[^A-Z0-9]//g
YPVr-i+<DOWN><LEFT>|<ESC><C-V>ky$pYjppVr $xrv
```

Replace `<DOWN>` with <kbd>↓</kbd>, `<LEFT>` with <kbd>←</kbd>, `<ESC>` with <kbd>esc</kbd> and `<C-V>` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Here's an animation of this script running (old version which uses a `V` instead of a `v`):

[image: Animation]

Explanation of the script:

```
:s/[^A-Z0-9]//g                               # Remove all the characters that are not uppercase or numbers using a Regex.
YPVr-                                         # Duplicate the current, and replace all the characters of the upper one with dashes.
     i+<DOWN><LEFT>|<ESC>                     # Insert a + on the upper line, and a | on the second line.
                         <C-V>ky$p            # Copy the + and | to the end of both lines.
                                  Yjpp        # Copy the upper line to the bottom two times.
                                      Vr $    # Replace the bottom most line with spaces and put the cursor on the last character.
                                          xrv # Remove the last character and replace the second last character with a v.
```

Comment: lowercase V, not uppercase V

Comment: One character more, but avoids the special escaped characters:  r|y uP$pYPVr-r+$.YjppVr $hrV

Comment: You can replace `i+↓←|␛␖ky$p` with `A+↓|␛␖ky0P` to save a byte.

Comment: Alternatively, replace the first eight strokes in Bryce’s approach with `I|<END>|␛`

Comment: I wonder if this has the most upvotes because of the cool picture.

Comment: @SirBidenXVII Probably.

Answer (score 10):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) 34 bytes

```
Ó[^A-Z0-9]
ys$|ÄVr-r+$.YLppVr x$rv
```

Note that this worked in an older version, but doesn't work in the current version on try it online. I changed `Ä` to `YP` which is functionally equivalent.

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w5NbXkEtWjAtOV0KeXMkfFlQVnItciskLllMcHBWciB4JHJ2&input=UHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyAmIENvZGUgR29sZg)

Explanation:

```
Ó[^A-Z0-9]
```

Remove everything except for digits and uppercase characters.

```
ys$|              "Surround this line with '|' characters.
    Ä             "Duplicate this line
     Vr-          "Replace this whole duplicated line with '-' characters
        r+        "replace the first character with '+'
          $       "Move to the end of the line, and
           .      "Repeat our last command. This is the same as 'r+'
            Y     "Yank the current line
              pp  "and paste it twice
             L    "At the end of our text
```

Now, the buffer looks like this:

```
+---+
|A51|
+---+
+---+
```

And our cursor is at the first column of the last line.

```
Vr                 "Change the whole last line to spaces
   x               "Delete a character
    $rv            "And change the last character to a 'v'
```

[Non-competing version: (31 bytes)](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w5PChEEtWjAtOV0KeXMkfFlQw5ItciskLllMcHDDkiB4JHJ2&input=UHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyAmIENvZGUgR29sZg)

Comment: I just noticed that the input `Programming Puzzles & Code Golf` produces the incorrect string `PP&CG` in the output. The `&` should be removed

Comment: @LuisMendo Aww, darn it! Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it sometime today.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan So, you fixed it, right? [when? will? you? finally? fix? it?]

Comment: I'm not getting any output on TIO?

Comment: @Downgoat V just recently had a huge update, and unfortunately it [borked some things](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/issues) I'm looking into it, but I'm not sure how long it'll take to fix.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan oh okay :( can you provide a link to a working version/github commit

Comment: @Downgoat I'm not sure when the last working commit was. A minor change fixes things though (see the new answer)

Answer (score 7):

## 16-bit x86 machine code, 72 bytes

In hex:

```
565789F731C9FCAC84C074143C5A77F73C4173083C3977EF3C3072EBAA41EBE75F5EE81500B07CAA51F3A4AB59E80A00B020F3AAB076AA91AAC351B02BAAB02DF3AAB82B10AB59C3
```

Parameters: `SI` = input string, `DI` - output buffer.

Outputs a NULL-terminated string with lines delimited by newline.
Uses input string as a temporary buffer.

```
56           push   si
57           push   di
89 f7        mov    di,si    ;Using source string as a buffer
31 c9        xor    cx,cx    ;Counter
fc           cld
_loop:
ac           lodsb
84 c0        test   al,al    ;Test for NULL
74 14        jz     _draw    ;Break
3c 5a        cmp    al,'z'   ;\
77 f7        ja     _loop    ; |
3c 41        cmp    al,'a'    ; \
73 08        jae    _stor    ;  >[A-Z0-9]?
3c 39        cmp    al,'9'   ; /
77 ef        ja     _loop    ; |
3c 30        cmp    al,'0'   ;/
72 eb        jb     _loop
_stor:
aa           stosb           ;Store char in the source buffer
41           inc    cx
eb e7        jmp    _loop
_draw:
5f           pop    di
5e           pop    si
e8 15 00     call   _line    ;Output the first line
b0 7c        mov    al,'|'   ;This proc upon return leaves '\n' in AH
aa           stosb           ;First char of the second line
51           push   cx
f3 a4        rep    movsb    ;Copy CX logo characters from the source buffer
ab           stosw           ;Outputs "|\n", which is still in AX
59           pop    cx
e8 0a 00     call   _line    ;Output the third line
b0 20        mov    al,0x20  ;Space
f3 aa        rep    stosb    ;Output it CX times
b0 76        mov    al,'v'
aa           stosb           ;Output the final 'v'
91           xchg   cx,ax    ;CX == 0
aa           stosb           ;NULL-terminate the string
c3           retn            ;Return to caller
_line:
51           push   cx
b0 2b        mov    al,'+'
aa           stosb
b0 2d        mov    al,'-'
f3 aa        rep    stosb     ;'-'*CX
b8 2b 10     mov    ax,0x102b ;"+\n"
ab           stosw
59           pop    cx
c3           retn
```

Comment: Uhh.. I have not done assembly code for while.

Comment: Me too. Started again about a week ago for golfing only

Comment: `3c 41        cmp    al,a'  ` shouldn't it be `3c 41        cmp    al,'a'  ` ?

Comment: @rav_kr, sure, thanks fo noticing. Missed a quote while replacing hex codes with characters for readability.

Answer (score 4):

### Lua, <s>145</s> 99 Bytes

Not much to say, manipulating strings is always wordy in lua :). Takes a command-line argument and output via STDOUT

**Thanks to @LeakyNun for saving me 45 Bytes !**

```lua
n=(...):gsub("[^%u%d]","")s="+"..("-"):rep(#n).."+\n"return s.."|"..n.."|\n"..s..(" "):rep(#n).."V"
```

**100 Bytes proposed by @LeakyNun**

```lua
n=(...):gsub("[^A-Z%d]","")s="+"..("-"):rep(#n).."+\n"return s.."|"..n.."|\n"..s..(" "):rep(#n).."V"
```

**OLD 145 Bytes**

```lua
g="|"..(...):gsub("%a+",function(w)return w:sub(1,1)end):gsub("%s",'').."|"S="+"..g.rep("-",#g-2).."+"p=print
p(S)p(g)p(S)p(g.rep(" ",#g-2).."v")
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
g="|"                            -- g is the second, and starts with a |
  ..(...):gsub("%a+",            -- append the string resulting of the iteration on each word
    function(w)                  -- in the input, applying an anonymous function
      return w:sub(1,1)          -- that return the first character of the word
    end):gsub("%s",'')           -- then remove all spaces
  .."|"                          -- and append a |
S="+"..g.rep("-",#g-2).."+"      -- construct the top and bot of the box
p=print                          -- alias for print
p(S)p(g)p(S)                     -- output the box
p(g.rep(" ",#g-2).."v")          -- output #g-2 spaces (size of the shortened name), then v
```

Comment: Uhh, do you mean output via STDOUT?

But I don't mind because ITS OPPOSITE DAY!!!

Comment: @MatthewRoh I meant outputing to the STDIN of your terminal ! (fixed... shame....)

Comment: `n=(...):gsub("[^A-Z%d]","")s="+"..("-"):rep(#n).."+\n"return s.."|"..n.."|\n"..s..(" "):rep(#n).."V"` is 100 bytes

Comment: @LeakyNun using the pattern `%u` we gain some more bytes. Anyway, thanks :) (will update the ungolfed later)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 43 bytes

```
[^A-Z\d]

.+
+$.&$*-+¶|$&|¶+$.&$*-+¶$.&$* V
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=W15BLVpcZF0KCi4rCiskLiYkKi0rwrZ8JCZ8wrYrJC4mJCotK8K2JC4mJCogVg&input=QXJlYSA1MQ)

This is the perfect challenge to demonstrate Retina, Martin Ender's golfing language.

This solution is divided into two steps (what we call stages), both stages being a replacement stage.

The first stage:

```
[^A-Z\d]
```

This matches the substrings which match `[^A-Z\d]`, which is the characters that are not uppercase and not digits, and then substitute them by nothing, meaning deleting them.

The second stage:

```
.+
+$.&$*-+¶|$&|¶+$.&$*-+¶$.&$* V
```

The `.+` matches the whole result, and then substitutes it with the second line.

In the second line:

- `$&` refers to the whole match
- `$.&` refers to the length of the whole match
- `$*` means take the previous integer, repeat the next character that many times. Here `$.&$*-` means to repeat `-` however long the match is.
- `¶` refers to a new-line.

Comment: Nice, I tried this earlier, but ended up with 54 bytes. An alternative for the first stage is `T\`dLp\`dL_` but it's the same length, unfortunately.

Comment: @MartinEnder What were your 54 bytes?

Comment: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBkTHBgZExfCl58JAp8CiQKwrYkX8K2JF_CtiRfClQyfmB8cGArLWAuKwpyYC5cRwogCi4uJAp2&input=OTkgQm90dGxlcyBvZiBCZWVy

Answer (score 4):

## Excel VBA, <s>375</s> <s>359</s> 358 bytes:

It works, I give up on trying to make it shorter...

Edit: Switched to case statement from if statements, -16 bytes

Edit2: Got rid of u and replaced with Len(b), -1 byte

```
Function b(x)
For i = 1 To Len(x)
a = Mid(x, i, 1)
e = Asc(a)
If e > 64 And e < 91 Or e > 47 And e < 58 Then b = b & a
Next i
For Z = 1 To 4
y = ""
Select Case Z
Case 2
y = "|" & b & "|"
Case 4
For i = 1 To Len(b)
y = y & " "
Next i
y = y & "v"
Case Else
y = "+"
For i = 1 To Len(b)
y = y & "-"
Next i
y = y & "+"
End Select
Debug.Print y
Next Z
End Function
```

Comment: Its good though, considering that VBA is sometimes rubbish.

Comment: I just do these for the challenge, I know I can't compete with VBA.  Usually end up super confused at the end after changing all the variables from names to single letters.

Comment: Yeah ikr So true

Comment: Can you remove the whitespace around operators?

Comment: They are added automatically by the program, I don't know if that's an option or not.

Comment: Laughed at "Got rid of u"

Comment: I think you can remove some whitespace. It is automatically added after you paste the golfed code.

Comment: I cannot run the code with whitespace removed because the VBA editor adds it automatically so I can't verify that it will run with it missing.

Comment: To justify removing whitespace, remove it in a text editor, then paste back into VBA. If VBA handles it correctly, you're good with the shortened version.

Comment: I've put it in notepad, removed spaces, pasted back into the VBA editor and spaces are back.  The editor adds them, if you delete them in the editor and click the mouse anywhere, it adds them.  I cannot test the program without them.

Comment: Yep. But if the code you start with doesn't have spaces and they are automatically inserted by the VBA editor and then it works, you have tested your space-reduced code.

Comment: And do look up the String function.

Comment: `For Each x in Split([A1]):a=a+IIf(x Like"[a-zA-Z]*",Left(x,1),""):Next:s="+"+String(Len(a),45)+"+":?s:?"|"a"|":?s:?Spc(Len(a))"v` - 128 Bytes

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <strike>183 177</strike> 165 bytes

```
string h(string s){s=string.Concat(s.Where(n=>n>47&n<58|n>64 &n<91));int m=s.Length;var x=new string('-',m);return$"+{x}+\n|{s}|\n+{x}+\n{new string(' ', m + 1)}v";}
```

multiplying chars is terrible in C#.
suggestions appreciated

thanks alot to aloisdg for -18 bytes

Comment: You can replace `| |` with `|`

Comment: You can use string interpolation `return$"+{x}+\n|{s}|\n+{x}+\n{new string(' ',m+1)}v";}`

Comment: thats a sweet method!

Comment: You can replace `string.Join("", ` with `string.Concat(`

Comment: You can replace your `where` lambda with `(n=>n>47&n<58|n>64&n<91))`

Comment: i thought about doing ascii comparisons

Comment: You can remove the space after the `return`

Comment: Also I would use a lambda this anonymous function are allowed. `s=>{..};` instead of `string h(string s){..};`

Comment: You can remove the space in `n>64 &n<91`

Comment: I added all this edits to the [tips for code golfinf in C#](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top) thread :)

Comment: good job!, lemme add some more edits

Comment: @downrep_nation - Can't you shorten `m + 1`, or is the whitespace significant?

Comment: @owacoder He doesnt need it. I wrote it without earlier :)

Comment: If you change the Where-lambda to Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit) you should be able to save a few characters,

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by adding `using S=System.String;` and replacing `string` with `S`.

Comment: 148 bytes by using a regex and eliminating the variable `m`: `string h(string s){s=Regex.Replace(s,"[^A-Z0-9]","");var x=new string('-',s.Length);return$"+{x}+\n|{s}|\n+{x}+\n{new string(' ', s.Length + 1)}v";}`

Answer (score 3):

## [2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), <s>36</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

Presenting **2sable** :). Although it has a lot in common with 05AB1E, this one actually auto joins the stack rather than outputting the top of the stack. Code:

```
žKA-Ã©g'-×'+DŠJDU„
|Â®sX¶®gð×'v
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ No more golfing or language switches! Leave it where it is now! :P

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Hahaha, it is still 3 _painful_ bytes away from your answer :P.

Comment: Haha, I was celebrating when I saw it 7 bytes longer, and then slowly watched the gap disappear, one by one...

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

```
(s,t=s.replace(/[^0-9A-Z]/g,``),g=c=>t.replace(/./g,c))=>`${s=`+${g(`-`)}+
`}|${t}|
${s}${g(` `))v`
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 107 Bytes

This answer is heavily based on the answer by *Zylviij* and the comments by *nimi*. I would have added more comments to that answer, but alas, I don't have enough rep.

```haskell
o n=t++'|':f++"|\n"++t++(f>>" ")++"v"where f=[c|c<-n,any(==c)$['0'..'9']++['A'..'Z']];t='+':(f>>"-")++"+\n"
```

Additional tricks used:

- Replaced `intersect` by its implementation so the import can be dropped. (Side note: the implementation is nearly verbatim the library one, I couldn't find a shorter version.)
- Moved the helper functions into the `where` clause so functions can use the `n` parameter internally.
- After that, `(#)` was short enough to be inlined.
- Put everything on one line to limit extra whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5, <s>114</s> <s>93</s> 112 bytes:

```
import re;Y=re.findall('[A-Z0-9]',input());I='+'+'-'*len(Y)+'+\n|';print(I+''.join(Y)+I[::-1]+'\n'+' '*len(Y)+'v')
```

A full program. Basically uses a regular expression to match all occurrences of uppercase letters and numbers, then creates the box of the exact size based on the length of the list of matches, and finally puts the joined list of matches "inside" it.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/3b6z1g)

Comment: It's missing the bottom 'v'.

Comment: @CarlesCompany It's fixed, at the cost of 19 more bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>121</s> 124 bytes

Fixed stupid mistake

```
s=''
for i in input():_=ord(i);s+=("",i)[91>_>64or 47<_<58]
x=len(s)
c='+'+"-"*x+'+'
print(c+"\n|"+s+"|\n"+c+"\n"+" "*x+"v")
```

does not import libraries like other python answer.

Comment: [Does not work correctly. -1](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#s%3D%27%27%0Afor%20i%20in%20input%28%29%3As%2B%3D%28%22%22%2Ci%29%5B%27%5B%27%3Ei%3E%27%40%27or%27%2F%27%3Ci%3C%27%3A%27%5D%0Ax%3Dlen%28s%29%0Ac%3D%27%2B%27%2B%22-%22%2ax%2B%27%2B%27%0Aprint%28c%2B%22%5Cn%7C%22%2Bs%2B%22%7C%5Cn%25s%5Cn%22%25c%2B%22%20%22%2ax%2B%22v%22%29) Notify if you fix.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Fixed. Thank you

Comment: Actually, the link was golfing some code, and that's why I put it there.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 149 bytes

```java
s->{s=s.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9]","");String t="+",r;int l=s.length(),i=l;for(;i-->0;t+="-");for(r=(t+="+\n")+"|"+s+"|\n"+t;++i<l;r+=" ");return r+"v";}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVA9b8IwEN35FScPVSKTiA4dkBsk6NCpgMRWSiUTHGpwbGRfUhWa355e2kidKirZ1n28d37vDrKWyWF3bHMjQ4Anqe1lAKAtKl/IXMG8SwFW6LXdQx71QYgF1Ru6dAJK1DnMwUIGbUgml5CF1KuToQlTYyK2fp0mz6NkvGFDxmLRD8GMcTb0gn4DQwyj7B7fonioMyMK5yOhk2QyEsgzlhCtK/ks6lL@YlnM2SfjgV5KOArO9b0RnrpAYK@w8hY8ZzUTTSt@pJ6qrSGpveLa6R2U5Lm3td6AjHvDHwFVmboK0xO10NjIpnnElt7tvSzLTv@yOp@NCnADD26n4NGZgsXfi/mbv0KZH2FR03qNe78Kn3ol4e72Km48hq1D7NS4ArZK@f9QZj1lUcDsl9IMmvYL)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                     // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s=s.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9]","");
                         //  Leave only the uppercase letters and digits
  String t="+",          //  Temp-String, starting at "+"
         r;              //  Result-String
  int l=s.length(),      //  Amount of uppercase letters and digits `l`
  i=l;for(;i-->0;t+="-");//  Loop and append `l` amount of "-" to the temp-String
  for(r=(t+="+\n")       //  Append "+" and a new-line to the temp-String
        +"|"+s+"|\n"+t;  //  Set the result to `t`, "|", modified input, "|", new-line, `t`
                         //  all appended to each other
      ++i<l;r+=" ");     //  Loop and append `l` amount of spaces to the result
  return r+"v";}         //  Return the result-String with appended "v"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 57 bytes

**56 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```pl
y/a-z //d;$d="-"x y///c;$_="+$d+
|$_|
+$d+
".$"x y///c.v
```

I originally tried to make this only using regexes, but it was much larger than I'd hoped, so I've used some string repetition instead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79SP1G3SkFfP8VaJcVWSVepQqFSX18/2Vol3lZJWyVFm6tGJb6GC8xS0lOBSeuV/f8fUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNarJCYl6LgnJ@SquCen5P2L7@gJDM/r/i/bgEA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 39 bytes

```
cFDh~u{!Ih(sil\-*\+R\+sj\|i\|++jild*\v+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=cFDh%7Eu%7B%21Ih%28sil%5C-%2a%5C%2BR%5C%2Bsj%5C%7Ci%5C%7C%2B%2Bjild%2a%5Cv%2B&input=Area+51&warnings=0)

12 bytes of mini-string creation, 20 bytes of formatting. Joy!

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
Jj*\-lK@jrG1UTz"++"jK"||"JtXJ"-+"" v
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%0A%0AJj%2a%5C-lK%40jrG1UTz%22%2B%2B%22jK%22%7C%7C%22JtXJ%22-%2B%22%22+v&input=99+Bottles+Of+Beer&debug=0)

Note the newline in the start.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 113 bytes

```
def f(n):c=filter(lambda x:x.isupper()^x.isdigit(),n);L=len(c);h='+'+L*'-'+'+\n';return h+'|'+c+'|\n'+h+' '*L+'v'
```

Comment: Can you use ascii in Python? If yes you can use `47<x<58|64<x<91` :)

Comment: @aloisdg Unlike C/C++, Python doesn't use an integral `char` type - all characters in Python strings are themselves strings, and cannot be directly compared with integers. It would need to be `47<ord(x)<58or 64<ord(x)<91`.

Comment: `[x for x in n if x.isupper()^x.isdigit()]` is one byte shorter than `filter(lambda x:x.isupper()^x.isdigit(),n)`

Comment: @LeakyNun: filter will return a string, but the list comprehension will return a list, which won't be usable in the return value expression.

Comment: Why XOR? Can't you use OR instead? XOR is more complex, and thus slower AFAIK. `x.isupper()^x.isdigit()` -> `x.isupper()|x.isdigit()`

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 35 bytes

```
Ά+,Alγ/x"[^A-Z0-9]"1'+'-'|γS*lγ" 'v
```

I need a shorter way to remove all but caps & numbers...

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>171</s> 163

Function `f()` modifies its input and prints out the result.

```
l;f(char*n){char*p=n,*s=n,c[99];for(;*n;++n)isupper(*n)+isdigit(*n)?*p++=*n:0;*p=0;memset(c,45,l=strlen(s));c[l]=0;printf("+%s+\n|%s|\n+%s+\n%*.cv\n",c,s,c,l,32);}
```

### Test Program

Requires one parameter, the string to use in the favicon:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char *input=malloc(strlen(argv[1])+1);
    strcpy(input,argv[1]);
    f(input);
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you copy the argv element?

Comment: Because the function modifies its input. I'm not sure modifying the parameters in place is defined behavior.

Comment: never thought about this... according to this SO answer it should be fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/963504/3700391

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 161

```
import Data.List
r=replicate
l=length
f n=intersect n$['0'..'9']++['A'..'Z']
t n='+':(r(l$f n)'-')++"+\n"
o n=(t n)++"|"++(f n)++"|\n"++(t n)++(r(l$f n)' ')++"V"
```

#### Usage

```
o"Stack Overflow"
+--+
|SO|
+--+
  V

o"Area 51"
+---+
|A51|
+---+
   V
```

Comment: You're using `replicate`, `length` and `f` exclusively in this combination, so you can merge them into one function: `r=replicate.length.f` and call it like `r  n '-'`.  You can save even more bytes by using an infix operator: `(#)=replicate.length.f` and `n#'-'` / `n#' '`. Additionally `replicate.length` is  `>>` (with a singleton string instead of a char), so it's: `(#)=(>>).f` and `n#"-"` / `n#" "`, both without `( )` around it.

Comment: ... also: no need for the `( )` around `t n` and `f n`. `"|"++` is `'|':`. All in all: `o n=t n++'|':f n++"|\n"++t n++n#" "++"V"`.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>99</s> 74 bytes

```
s=$(sed s/[^A-Z0-9]//g);a=${s//?/-};echo -e "+$a+\n|$s|\n+$a+\n${s//?/ }v"
```

Usage: Run the above command, type the site name, press enter and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (send 'end of file').

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 34 bytes

```
t1Y24Y2hm)T45&Ya'+|+'!wy&h10M~'v'h
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dDFZMjRZMmhtKVQ0NSZZYScrfCsnIXd5JmgxME1-J3YnaA&input=J0FyZWEgNTEn)

```
t        % Implicit input. Duplicate
1Y2      % Uppercase letters
4Y2      % Digit characters
h        % Concatenate horizontally: string with uppercase letters and digits
m        % True for input chars that are uppercase letters or digits
)        % Keep only those
T45&Ya   % Pad up and down with character 45, which is '-'. Gives three-row char array
'+|+'!   % Push this string and transpose into a column vector
wy       % Swap, duplicate the second array from the top. This places one copy of the
         % column vector below and one above the three-row char array
&h       % Contatenate all stack arrays horizontally. This gives the box with the text
10M      % Retrieve the string with selected letters
~        % Logical negate. Gives zeros, which will be displayes as spaces
'v'      % Push this character
h        % Concatenate horizontally with the zeros.
         % Implicitly display the box with the text followed by the string containing
         % the zero character repeated and the 'v'
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 108 bytes

```
cat(x<-gsub("(.*)","+\\1+\n",gsub(".","-",y<-gsub("[^A-Z0-9]","",s))),"|",y,"|\n",x,gsub("."," ",y),"v",sep="")
```

### Explanation

Going from the inside out (because who doesn't love assigning global variables from inside a regex), assuming `s` is our input string:

`y<-gsub("[^A-Z0-9]","",s)` keeps capitals and numbers, assigns the resulting value to y.

`gsub(".","-",y<-...)` replaces all characters with hyphens in the above.

`x<-gsub("(.*)","+\\1+\n",gsub(...))` chucks a `+` on either end of the row of hyphens, and a newline, and we store that as x.

The rest is pretty straightforward, output in the appropriate order, and use the fact that the number of spaces before the `v` will be the same as the length of y.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 41

```
"||"q_'[,65>A,s+--*__"+-"er_@\_,((S*]N*'v
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%7C%7C%22q_'%5B%2C65%3EA%2Cs%2B--*__%22%2B-%22er_%40%5C_%2C((S*%5DN*'v&input=Programming%20Puzzles%20%26%20Code%20Golf)

Answer (score 1):

### APL, <strike>52</strike> 49 bytes

```
{x⍪2⌽'v'↑⍨≢⍉x←⍉z⍪⍨(z←'+|+')⍪'-','-',⍨⍪⍵/⍨⍵∊⎕D,⎕A}
```

(down to 49 thanks to the comment).

Comment: `{x⍪2⌽'v'↑⍨≢⍉x←⍉z⍪⍨(z←'+|+')⍪'-','-',⍨⍪⍵/⍨⍵∊⎕D,⎕A}` (You never parenthesize one of the arguents in a reversed argument function when golfing. It always can be in normal order to save a byte.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/tree/45273ddf926eb9cb054f17a113540959cf32face), 61 bytes

Linked to the repository at Jul 7 to ensure backward compatibility.

```
lybL:{,."-"}ac:"+"c:"+"rcAw@NNw"|"Bw?wBwNwAwNwL:{," "w}a,"v"w
```

#### Non-competing, 53 bytes

```
lL:"-"rjb:"+"c:"+"rcAw@NNw"|"Bw?wBwNwAwNw" ":Ljbw"v"w
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=bEw6Ii0icmpiOiIrImM6IisicmNBd0BOTncifCJCdz93QndOd0F3TnciICI6TGpidyJ2Inc&input=IkJyYWNoeWxvZyI)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 119 bytes

```
h=a=>"+"+"-".repeat(a.length)+"+\n";j=a=>(a=a.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g,""),h(a)+"|"+a+"|\n"+h(a)+" ".repeat(a.length)+"v");
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 52 bytes

```
'v'(<3 _2)}4{.1":]<@#~2|'/9@Z'&I.[9!:7@'+++++++++|-'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0G9TF3Dxlgh3kiz1qRaz1DJKtbGQbnOqEZd39IhSl3NUy/aUtHK3EFdGwZqdNX/pyZn5CukKag7FqUmKpgaqv8HAA)

```
   [9!:7@'+++++++++|-'            Set the box drawing characters.
        '/9@Z'&I.                 Interval index, 1 for numbers, 3 for 
                                  uppercase letters.
          ]  #~2|                 Mod 2, and filter
                                  the characters that correspond to 1s.
           <@                     Put them in a box.
           1":                    Convert to a character matrix, so we can do stuff to it.
           4{.                    Add a 4th line filled with spaces   
       'v'(<3 _2)}                Insert a “v” at 3,−2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 81 bytes (78 + `-p` flag)

```
gsub(/[^A-Z\d]/,'')
gsub(/.+/){"+#{k=?-*s=$&.size}+
|#{$&}|
+#{k}+
#{' '*s}v"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 112 bytes

```
<?$s=str_replace('-',' ',$m=ereg_replace('.','-',$n=ereg_replace('[^A-Z0-9]','',$x)));echo"+$m+
|$n|
+$m+
$s",v;
```

- PHP<5.4 with `register_globals=1`, call `php-cgi -f <filename> x="<name>";echo""`
- add `<pre>` after `echo"` for call in web browser `<scriptpath>?x=<name>`;
- for PHP>=5.4: replace `$x` with `$_GET[x]` (+6)
  or with `$argv[1]` to call `php <filename> "<name>";echo""` (+6)
- you may want to add `-d error_reporting=0` to cli options

There are times when I love that PHP accepts newlines in constant strings.

- `str_repeat` looked like a buddy here, but costs 3 bytes
- `<?=(<assignments>)?"<output>".v:0` costs 1 byte
- `<?=(<assignments>),"
  <output>",v;` does neither cost nor save, but adds a leading blank line to the output

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp (Lispworks), 159 bytes bytes

```
(defun f(s)(labels((p(c l)(dotimes(i l)(format t"~A"c))))(let((l(length s)))#1=(p"+"1)#2=(p"-"l)#3=(format t"+~%")(format t"|~A|~%"s)#1##2##3#(p" "l)(p"v"1))))
```

ungolfed:

```
(defun f (s)
  (labels ((p (c l)
             (dotimes (i l)
               (format t "~A" c))))
    (let ((l (length s)))
      #1=(p "+" 1)
      #2=(p "-" l)
      #3=(format t "+~%")
      (format t "|~A|~%" s)
      #1#
      #2#
      #3#
      (p " " l)
      (p "v" 1))))
```

Usage:

```
CL-USER 2 > (f "so")
+--+
|so|
+--+
  v
NIL

CL-USER 3 > (f "pcg")
+---+
|pcg|
+---+
   v
NIL
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) 2.0 `-R`, <s>37</s> 36 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Shaggy*

```
r/\W|\a/
'+²¬qUÊî-
[V'|+U+'|V'viUÊî]
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9cV3xcYS8KJyuyrHFVyu4tCltWJ3wrVSsnfFYndmlVyu5d&input=IkFyZWEgNTEiCgotUg==)

Comment: `r/\W|\a/` should save a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC 3, 131 bytes

```
INPUT N$WHILE""<N$C$=SHIFT(N$)IF@0<C$&&"[">C$||"/"<C$&&":">C$THEN W$=W$+C$
WEND
L=LEN(W$)H$="+"+"-"*L+"+
?H$?"|"+W$+"|
?H$?" "*L+"v
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>129</s> 126 bytes

```
{s:String->val x=s.filter{it in('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')}
val h="-".repeat(x.length)
"+$h+\n|$x|\n+$h+\n${" ".repeat(x.length)}v"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xC8IwEIX3/oojFJNQDDo4WGylOLg4CG7iEjBpg2kq1yjV2t9eUxy96XHvu3vv1nhr3KgfDmppHJNYtikUiPK1OXk0rsw59BGEeUoLGrKxb9OfM8@nVZe1QhvrFfbGQ3hBCyoEPVOeMLqY5JryIZrQKiNzIlDdlfSsE1a50lc8IklcJRf3ibvPxf103BP4J4cnGcapyj3Ee6YZKnk9GKcYh20K5IhNibKuQzc4Pt5vq1qYwa65Ktg3VhPOo2EswhGsll8)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 128 bytes

```cs
x=>{x=Replace(x,"[^A-Z0-9]","");Write("{0}{1}\n{0}{2}","+"+"+\n".PadLeft(x.Length+2,'-'),$"|{x}|","v".PadLeft(x.Length+1,' '));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/RSsMwFIbv9xQhiG1ZWteBF1o7KCLeFCybIOgUQndag21SknTGdXn1xXbX41wcOP934PtLFZaKuazUTPAHpSXj9apKnUlXg0nX0DW0BN8Q/PGVhe@L8O4TE4yD5E0yDT4eFnaI7ZZPe2nHaD7NluOooLscKu2bKAde6@/5knihF5ArfByMPY7o/gIUEw95QZBYl8wqHxdS1JK27SiFiv5waECha/QodoCeRVONHrOzSM44@MH5ZaNp@YNe9iCrRvxeIjIJFN3GY@ROopt6K3fT32/@lIY2egWjozXUfUPlk@kkKDUR0wnMPw)