# This isn't rocket science

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Write a program or function that takes in a single-line string. You can assume it only contains [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). Print or return a string of an ASCII art rocket such as

```
  |
 /_\
 |E|
 |a|
 |r|
 |t|
 |h|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

with the input string written from top to bottom on the fuselage. In this case the input was `Earth`. The height of the rocket (including flames) is always the length of the string plus five.

Each line in the output may have up to two trailing spaces and there may be a single optional trailing newline. **The shortest code in bytes wins.**

### More Examples:

```
[empty string]

  |
 /_\
 |_|
/___\
 VvV

a

  |
 /_\
 |a|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV

|0

  |
 /_\
 |||
 |0|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV

\/\

  |
 /_\
 |\|
 |/|
 |\|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV

 _ _ [note trailing space]

  |
 /_\
 | |
 |_|
 | |
 |_|
 | |
 |_|
/___\
 VvV

    [4 spaces]

  |
 /_\
 | |
 | |
 | |
 | |
 |_|
/___\
 VvV

SPACEY

  |
 /_\
 |S|
 |P|
 |A|
 |C|
 |E|
 |Y|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=91182,OVERRIDE_USER=26997;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11249/194). There may be others which are close enough that this counts as a dupe.

Comment: Are withespace characters (newline, tab and space) considered as printable ASCII? if yes should we take them into account and how (mainly for tab and newline)

Comment: @Sefa Spaces yes. No to other whitespace. As the [linked wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) indicates.

Comment: D'oh, I saw the title and expected something about brain surgery. :(

Comment: And if the bottom points at the sky you will not go to space today.

Comment: It's not rocket appliances!

Comment: "It worked in Kerbal Space Program..."

Comment: Could I enter with PETSCII characters rather than ASCII? See -> https://sta.c64.org/cbm64pet.html

Answer (score 53):

## Excel VBA, <s>142</s>  <s>179</s>  <s>175</s> <s>160</s> 155 bytes

**Instruction:**

Set the worksheet of Excel where cell A1 is input and column C as the output. <s>Set the text alignment in column C to center</s>. Write and run the following code in the Immediate Window:

```vb
[C1]="|":[C2]="/_\":T=[A1]&"_":For i=1To Len(T):Cells(i+2,3)="|"&Mid(T,i,1)&"|":Next:Cells(i+2,3)="/__\":Cells(i+3,3)="VvV":[C:C].HorizontalAlignment=-4108
```

**Ungolfed the code:**

```vb
Sub R()
    [C1] = "|"
    [C2] = "/_\"
    T = [A1]&"_"
    
    For i = 1 To Len(T)
        Cells(i + 2, 3) = "|" & Mid(T, i, 1) & "|"
    Next
    
    Cells(i + 2, 3) = "/__\"
    Cells(i + 3, 3) = "VvV"
    [C:C].HorizontalAlignment = -4108   'Set the text alignment in column C to center
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** The font and the color are just a personal choice.

---

*15 bytes saved due to edc65's suggestion. Thanks.*

*5 bytes saved due to Taylor Raine's suggestion. Thanks.*

Comment: Save 15 bytes adding `"_"` to T. Like this `[C1]="|":[C2]="/_\":T=[A1]&" ":For i=1To Len(T):Cells(i+2,3)="|"&Mid(T,i,1)&"|":Next:Cells(i+2,3)="/__\":Cells(i+4,3)="VvV":Columns(3).HorizontalAlignment=-4108`

Comment: (ok there is an error in my code and it's too late to edit it. But you get the idea)

Comment: @edc65 I don't get the idea. Your code is exactly the same with mine so what should I edit to save 15 bytes?

Comment: I edited it some times, look at it again

Comment: @edc65 Ahh, I get it. Very clever. Thank you so much :)

Comment: 154 Bytes: `[C:C].HorizontalAlignment=-4108:[C1]="|":[C2]="/_\":T=[A1]&"_":For i=1To Len(T):Cells(i+2,3)="|"&Mid(T,i,1)&"|":Next:Cells(i+2,3)="/__\":Cells(i+3,3)="VvV`

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 just in case you did not know, if you end your immediate window function with an unclosed string, VBA does not throw an error so if you move `:Cells(i+2,3)="/_‌​_\"` or `:Cells(i+3,3)="Vv‌​V"` to the end you can drop the terminal `"` for -1 byte :)

Comment: Huh, I think you are missing a `_` in the `Cells(i+2,3)` call - Anyways, an alternate approach, also 154 bytes: `[C1]="  |":[C2]=" /_\":T=[A1]&"_":For i=1To Len(T):Cells(i+2,3)=" |"&Mid(T,i,1)&"|":Next:Cells(i+2,3)="/___\":Cells(i+3,3)=" VvV":[C:C].Font.Name="Courier`

Comment: Or you could get it down to 151 bytes, keeping the centering aspect `[C:C].HorizontalAlignment=3:[C1]="|":[C2]="/_\":T=[A1]&"_":For i=1To Len(T):Cells(i+2,3)="|"&Mid(T,i,1)&"|":Next:Cells(i+2,3)="/___\":Cells(i+3,3)="VvV`

Comment: It seems as though this just centers the text rather than outputting a space before the `|<insert char here>|`

Answer (score 32):

### Perl 6, 75 bytes

```
"  |\n /_\\".say;" |$_|".say for slurp.chomp.comb;" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV".say;
```

Comment: `slurp.chomp.comb`... Perl is weird.

Comment: **SLURP!!!** **CHOMP!!!** **COMB!!** Here comes the Perl monster!

Comment: Note that by using a function and concatanation you can cut out a lot: `{[~] "  |\n /_\\\n",|(" |$_|\n"for $_.comb)," |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"}` 65 bytes

Comment: But you can go even lower by borrowing from JS's: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX9cuprhaSUGhhktBPz4mhkuhWkOpRiW@hkspLb9IoVgvOT83SbNWoQYooh8fD1YRVhamVPvfmqs4EWSIhlJJanFJZl66kqb1fwA

Answer (score 25):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54

Straightforward

```
x=>`  |
 /_\\
 |${[...x+'_'].join`|
 |`}|
/___\\
 VvV`
```

**Test**

```js
f=x=>`  |
 /_\\
 |${[...x+'_'].join`|
 |`}|
/___\\
 VvV`

function update() {
  O.textContent=f(I.value)
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value='hello' oninput='update()'><pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 17):

### Actually, 40 bytes

```
"/___\
 VvV",'_o"|
 |"j'|o" |"+"  |
 /_\
```

Yes, those newlines are supposed to be there.

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Ii9fX19cCiBWdlYiLCdfbyJ8CiB8ImonfG8iIHwiKyIgIHwKIC9fXA&input=InwwIg)

Explanation:

Newlines are represented by `\n` for easier formatting

```
"/___\\n VvV",'_o"|\n |"j'|o" |"+"  |\n /_\
"/___\\n VvV"                                create the bottom of the rocket
             ,'_o                            get input, append a "_" (for the last section before the jets)
                 "|\n |"j                    insert "|\n |" between every pair of characters
                         '|o                 append "|"
                            " |"+            prepend " |"
                                 "  |\n /_\  create the nose cone
```

Comment: Your program looks depressingly similar to an exploded rocket.

Answer (score 16):

## C, <s>83</s>, 82 bytes

```
F(char*c){for(puts("  |\n /_\\");*c;printf(" |%c|\n",*c++));puts(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");}
```

Test main:

```
int main() {
  F("");
  F("a");
  F("|0");
  F("\\/\\");
  F(" _ _ ");
  F("    ");
  F("SPACEY");
}
```

Comment: I worked out my own C solution, and it turned out being exactly yours, character for character.  +1 from me.

Comment: On phone and too lazy to SSH, so this is untested, but should work. Saves 2 bytes (if I counted correctly): `F(char*c){for(puts("  |\n /_\\");*c;printf(" |%c|\n",*c++),puts(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");}`

Comment: @algmyr saves one byte, actually, because the last `puts` has to be executed only once, not after every `printf`. But yes, 1 byte saved, yay!

Comment: Right. I'll blame that on golfing when I should have been sleeping.

Comment: Is this not 88 bytes?

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>93</s> <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 61 bytes

A FGITW. Can probably be heavily golfed. Suggestions welcome.

**Edit:** 27 bytes thanks to Mego. 4 bytes thanks to TheBikingViking. 1 byte thanks to user3030010.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##HYlBCsIwFET3OcXwodCiGHFZcCHiXhAK4pcQkWBEk5IUqZC7x8QZePNgxu/08G6TzZbzS79vd425D0QEJAGpWCA1MQmpVPXhM5SvocQOiVZPb107L0hRl40PiLAOF6IlSFekdSWzZK4CVfqXkrqn425/ONO1FxiDdRNMGzvkHw)

```python
lambda x:r"""  |
 /_\
 |%s|
/___\
 VvV"""%"|\n |".join(x+"_")
```

Answer (score 10):

## PHP, <s>73</s> <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 62 bytes

```
  |
 /_\
 |<?=join('|
 |',str_split($argv[1]._))?>|
/___\
 VvV
```

Takes the string to print on the fuselage as the first argument from the command line when the script is called.

Improvements:

1. Saved a byte by replacing \n with a real LF newline in the first argument of `join`.
2. Saved three more bytes by appending the rocket base with a single underscore to the input
3. Thanks to [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel): Saved 7 more bytes by taking advantage of the fact that PHP used to be the "Hypertext preprocessor" so you can output as much text as you want and start the code somewhere in the middle.

[Try it online!](https://beta.tehplayground.com/wBnYIY5ZjParcDZa)

This was fun! :-)

Sample calls:

```
php rocket.php ""
php rocket.php EARTH
php rocket.php "This is a very long rocket"
```

Comment: 62 bytes: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c640244e19b43a44c364a971ea796f277e4dbf4

Comment: Nice golfing! I totally forgot about that possibility. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I saved 2 bytes on the first line. You had 2 extra trailing spaces on it. That was something I wasn't expecting to find, I must say.

Comment: I know, that was really dumb but also really hard to spot. I only noticed once I came up with 64 bytes on your improved version and had to find out why.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 58 bytes

```haskell
f s="  |\n /_\\\n |"++((:"|\n |")=<<s)++"_|\n/___\\\n VvV"
```

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, <s>57</s> 55 bytes

-2 bytes by @ValueInk
-5 bytes by assuming that there is no newline in the input, as suggested by @manatwork. Newline-less input can be provided for example with `echo -n`, like `echo -n hey | ruby rocket.rb`.

```rb
puts'  |
 /_\
 |'+gets.chars*'|
 |'+'|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV'
```

Old version, assumes newline in input:

## Ruby, <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```rb
puts'  |
 /_\
 |'+gets.chop.chars*'|
 |'+'|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV'
```

Comment: According to the question owner's [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91182/this-isnt-rocket-science/91206#comment222279_91182) the input will not contain newline character, so you can remove `.chop`.

Comment: @manatwork neat, thanks :)

Comment: If you use single quote strings, you should be able to replace both your `\\ ` with `\ `. (In single quoted strings, characters aren't escaped, except for `\'`.

Answer (score 9):

## [brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 179 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>-..[->+>++++<<]>>----.<<++++++++++.>.>>>+[-[--<]>>--]<.[-<+<++>>]<<+.---.<,[<<<.>.>.>.<.>,]<<<.[->>>+<<<]>.>.>>+++.<<.>.>>.<...---.<.<<.>>>------.[-<<<+<+>>>>]<<<.<.
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=Pi1bLVstPF0-Pis8XT4tLi5bLT4rPisrKys8PF0-Pi0tLS0uPDwrKysrKysrKysrLj4uPj4-K1stWy0tPF0-Pi0tXTwuWy08KzwrKz4-XTw8Ky4tLS0uPCxbPDw8Lj4uPi4-LjwuPixdPDw8LlstPj4-Kzw8PF0-Lj4uPj4rKysuPDwuPi4-Pi48Li4uLS0tLjwuPDwuPj4-LS0tLS0tLlstPDw8KzwrPj4-Pl08PDwuPC4&input=QUxMQUhVIEFLQkFS)

Comment: @user00001 This phrase is used by all Muslims worldwide, not just the terrorist. Do you really think that the terrorists represent all Muslims?

Comment: @user00001 however, this phrase "Allahu akbar" is still in use in Muslim communities. [The reaction probably depends on the tone in which it is shouted though. If it was shouted in a normal tone, people would probably assume that someone had had an accident and was shouting in pain. A bunch of us would probably rush towards the noise to see if we could help. // If it were in a rude tone, and you happened to be wearing a loose jacket, and you were doing something suspicious,  you'd...](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-you-shout-Allahu-Akbar-at-a-crowded-terminal/answer/Harish-Raman-8)

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>44</s> 37 bytes

**7 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.**

```
$
_
.
¶ |$0|
$
¶/___\¶ VvV
^
  |¶ /_\
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JApfCi4KwrYgfCQwfAokCsK2L19fX1zCtiBWdlYKXgogIHzCtiAvX1w&input=Q09ERSBHT0xG)

Comment: leaves a gap on a row at the bottom :( for "Space, the final frontier."

Comment: @xQbert Works for me, can you attach a TIO link?

Comment: odd, it works fine for me now...  ah my error had a newline at the end.

Comment: Retina is the only language I know which adding a trailing newline can completely change the program.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>37</s> 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;”_⁾ |;Ð€ŒB;“/___\“ VvV”“  |“ /_\”;Y
```

<s>Same score as existing entry, but</s> uses a fun new feature - `ŒB`, the vectorised version of `ŒḄ`, known as bounce. Bouncing is running through a list to its end and then back `x[:-1]+x[::-1]` e.g.: `bounce("codegolf") == "codegolflogedoc"`.

-1 byte thanks to Dennis (use the vectorised version of bounce)

How?

```
;”_⁾ |;Ð€ŒB;“/___\“ VvV”“  |“ /_\”;Y - argument: a string, S
                        “  |“ /_\”   - the top of the rocket ["  |", " /_\"] 
;”_                                  - concatenate to make S=S+"_"
   ⁾ |;                              - concatenate to make c=" |"+c
       Ð€                            - map over right argument i.e. for c in S
         ŒB                          - bounce! With vectorisation c[:-1]+c[::-1]
                                       e.g. " |B" -> " |B| "
           ;                         - concatenate with
            “/___\“ VvV”             - the bottom of the rocket ["/___\", " VvV"]
                                  ;  - concatenate the top with everything else
                                   Y - join with line feeds
```

Test it on [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KAnV_igb4gfDvDkOKCrMWSQjvigJwvX19fXOKAnCBWdlbigJ3igJwgIHzigJwgL19c4oCdO1k&input=&args=J0JvdW5jZXkgeWVjbnVvQic)

Comment: `ŒB` is short for `ŒḄ€`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

(Updated to work with latest version)

```
\_+2" ||
"m:"/___\
 VvV"+R"  |
 /_\
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C_%2B2%22+%7C%7C%0A%22m%3A%22%2F___%5C%0A+VvV%22%2BR%22++%7C%0A+%2F_%5C&input=Earth&warnings=0&hex=0)

Answer (score 5):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>41,</s> 39 bytes

```
ys$_òlé
òÎá|I |
Hr/$r\YO  |GpX2á_o VvV
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=eXMkX8OybMOpCsOyw47DoXxJIHwKSHIvJHJcWU8gIHwbR3BYMsOhX28gVnZW&input=RWFydGg)

Note that for some reason, the online interpreter was producing unexpected results, so I pushed a debug version to the online interpreter that runs a lot slower. It should produce the correct results now.

Since this program contains unprintable characters, here is a hexdump:

```
0000000: 7973 245f f26c e90a f2ce e17c 4920 7c0a  ys$_.l.....|I |.
0000010: 4872 2f24 725c 594f 2020 7c1b 4770 5832  Hr/$r\YO  |.GpX2
0000020: e15f 6f20 5676 56                        ._o VvV
```

Comment: Nice but it doesn't handle the spaces in "Space, the final frontier" quite right.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```powershell
"  |
 /_\"
$args|% t*y|%{" |$_|"}
" |_|
/___\
 VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBoYZLQT8@RolLJbEovbhGVaFEq7JGtVpJoUYlvkaplgvIiK/h0o@Pj4/hUggrC1P6D9TlnJGYk5Oal55apODpqQQA)

Abuses the default `Write-Output` at end of execution to stick a newline between each element, since these are all just literal strings on the pipeline. The only "tricky" bit is a loop through each element of the input `$args` as a char-array to get the body of the rocket.

*Uses literal newlines as pointed out by ConnorLSW to save some bytes.*
*-4 more bytes thanks to Veskah.*

Comment: you can put actual newlines in the string to save 3, the shell and ise execute fine without the `\r`

Comment: [t*y trick to save 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBoYZLQT8@RolLJbEovbhGVaFEq7JGtVpJoUYlvkaplgvIiK/h0o@Pj4/hUggrC1P6D9TlnJGYk5Oal55apODpqQQA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## R, 163 bytes

```
v=c();l="\n";for(i in 1:nchar(a<-scan(,"")))v=c(v,paste0(" |",strsplit(a,"")[[1]][i],"|",l,collapse=""));cat("  |",l," /_\\",l,v," |_|",l,"/___\\",l," VvV",sep="")
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
v=c()     #Empty vector
l="\n"    #Line break

for(i in 1:nchar(a<-scan(,"")))                  #For the number of character of the input
    v=c(v, paste0(" |",strsplit(a,"")[[1]][i],"|","\n",collapse=""))
    #This part cut the input into its letters, paste each letter between `|`'s, 
    #and a line break

cat("  |",l," /_\\",l,v," |_|",l,"/___\\",l," VvV",sep="") #Puts everything in the STDOUT,
                                                           #with spaces where needed
```

I don't really like the fact I had to put some spaces in the last line, but hey !

Answer (score 4):

### PHP, <s>108</s> <s>100</s> 88 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to business cat

-12 bytes thanks to YetiCGN

```
echo'  | 
 /_\\
';foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c){echo" |$c|
";}echo' |_|
/___\\
 VvV';
```

pretty straightforward

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/MSJymz)

Comment: You can save a lot of bytes by using `foreach(str_split($a)as$c)` instead of the other for loop. Also, you could put the $c directly in the string if you use double quotes: `echo" |$c| ....";`

Comment: @BusinessCat True, thanks the double quotes wasn't working with the array style thought due to the brackets not being interpreted

Comment: What about regular expression? `function f($a){echo'  |.␤ /_\\␤',preg_replace('/./',' |$0|␤',$a),' |_|␤/___\\␤ VvV';}`

Comment: Why even put a function around it? Replacing `$a` with `$argv[1]` and running from command line makes it much shorter.

Comment: @manatwork It's probably a valid alternative, but since i don't understand it and it's not the in the same spirit as mine, I will let you post it.

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <s>106</s> <s>97</s> <s>80</s> 74 bytes

```
s=>$@"  |
 /_\
 |{string.Join("|\n |",s.ToCharArray())}|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV";
```

I don't have C# 6 to try the above but I believe it will work

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

*Thanks to manatwork for pointing me in the right direction to save 17 bytes*

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to milk*

Comment: +1. Btw, trailing whitespaces are optional, so you can change it to: `using System.Linq;s=>$("  |\n /_\\\n{string.Join("",s.Select(c=>" |"+c+"|\n"))} |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");` (**100 bytes**)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I was just in the process of updating this after your comments to my previous answer :) Thanks for the help

Comment: You can save some characters by using a single string literal inside `Select`: `" |"+c+"|\n"` → `c+"|\n |"` together with moving the ` |` from after `{}` before it.

Comment: @manatwork I can't seem to get that to work

Comment: @manatwork Doesn't matter, got it to work and saved even more bytes

Comment: -1 byte with LINQ to use `s.Cast<char>()` instead of `s.ToCharArray()`. More importantly, -6 bytes by using verbatim strings (`@` fyi- after the `$` for interpolated verbatim string) to replace `\n` with newlines and `\\` with `\`, plus then you can even see the rocket in the source.

Comment: @milk adding linq means I have to add `using System.Linq` which is more bytes. Replacing new lines with new lines is still the same count but @ can save me one byte anyway thanks

Comment: New line is 1 byte compared to `\n`'s 2 bytes. So you'll save 5 more bytes by replacing them with new lines. Yes, if you're using Visual Studio then by default new lines will be 2 bytes, but you can open the source file in a hex editor (Visual Studio has one) and delete the carriage return characters. The output will still be the same.

Comment: @milk Ahhh okay me being daft, thanks

Comment: If u add the using 'using static System.String;' you can write Join instead of string.Join. C# 6.0 for the win.

Answer (score 4):

## C,  <s>131</s> , 121 bytes

```
#define P printf
main(){char s[99],*p=s;gets(s);P("  |\n /_\\\n");while(*p)P(" |%c|\n",*p++);P(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV\n");}
```

Comment: You can remove three characters by moving `p=s` into the initialization, and using `p` inside `scanf` : `main(){char s[99],*p=s;scanf("%s",p);P("  |\n /_\\\n");while(*p)P(" |%c|\n",*p++);P(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV\n");}`

Comment: ok.... i don't know why "scanf("%s", &s)" instead of "scanf("%s", s)"  print at end the correct result... at end because scanf not gets spaces i prefer the danger gets()...

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.  Thank you!

Comment: [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIUChoCgzryRNg6s42tIy1jo3MTNPQ7M6OSOxSKvANj21pFijWNM6Lb9II0BJQaEmJk9BPz4mJiZPSdNaq8BaEyhYo5oMFFbS0SrQ1ta0BgnEA/n68fFgdQphZWFg1bX///u6@ocDAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat If was possible the definition [#define P printf(" |] it would be less than 114...

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, 70 bytes

```
"  |`n /_\`n$(([char[]]$a|%{" |$_|"})-join("`n"))`n |_|`n/___\`n VvV
```

Set $a to input.

If it has to take input other than a variable it can be piped in:

```
"Hello World"|%{"  |`n /_\`n$(([char[]]$_|%{" |$_|"})-join("`n"))`n |_|`n/___\`n VvV "}
```

Example:

```
  |
 /_\
 |H|
 |e|
 |l|
 |l|
 |o|
 | |
 |W|
 |o|
 |r|
 |l|
 |d|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 50 bytes

```
"  |
 /_\\
 |"<>(#<>"|
 |"&/@#)<>"_|
/___\\
 VvV"&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of characters as input and returns a string as output.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>102</s> <s>99</s> 81 bytes

```java
a->{var r="  |\n /_\\\n |";for(var c:a)r+=c+"|\n |";return r+"_|\n/___\\\n VvV";}
```

3 bytes saved thanks to *@Jules*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bZBPa4NAEMXv@RTDnlYk2nPFQgg5NhSEQOkWmW5Ms6lZZRyFEP3sdv3Tg213YZf3Zob3Yy7Y4Ppy/Op1jlUFz2jsfQVgLGd0Qp3BfpAACZOxn6ClPiO9vQN6kfO7lXsqRjYa9mAhhh7XT/cGCSgWAK2yEKZKua8V0akgOZT0I3rkx9oX7VSgjGuyQL5InROm6TRyaA4i6vpoCCnrj9yFzFlNYY5wdaxy4hqBJlDOKpZCjHg/CpeyfVhqpUKllhak7v6y3Fk6yctmu3tdejskPos/yxmBx455kcaWNc/Iya3i7BoUNQelK3JupQ20HFsCLrZu4xsivEnPm7P@mZgju/4b)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                      // Method with character-array parameter and String return-type
  var r="  |\n /_\\\n |"; //  Result-String, starting with the top part:
                          //   |
                          //  /_\
                          //  |
  for(var c:a)            //  Loop over each character in the input-array:
    r+=c                  //   Append the character to the result-String,
        +"|\n |";         //   with trailing:
                          //    |
                          //  |
  return r                //  Return the result-String,
   +"_|\n/___\\\n VvV";}  //  appended with bottom part:
                          //   _|
                          // /___\
                          //  VvV
```

Comment: Couldn't you make a reference to System.out.println with a shorter name and call that?

Comment: @Trey Keown System.out.println is part of the test code, not the submission.

Comment: You can put  " |" onto the end of the 'r' initializer, then inside the loop move it to after the appended string, then you don't need at all in the string appended after the loop.  I think this would save you 5 bytes.

Comment: @Jules Thanks! Changed it, and it saves 3 bytes (not sure how you got to a save of 5, though).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>50</s> <s>47</s> <s>43</s> 37 bytes

```
I'_J"  |
 /_\"svy" |ÿ|"}"/___\
 VvV"»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=SSdfSiIgIHwKIC9fXCJzdnkiIHzDv3wifSIvX19fXAogVnZWIsK2w70&input=RWFydGg)

Saved 9 bytes thanks to Adnan.

Comment: String can also accept newlines in 05AB1E :p, like [this](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IkFiYwpkZWYi&input=).

Comment: @Adnan Nice, thanks! Any idea how to better get around the empty input?

Comment: I was thinking about an approach with `IðJ` at the beginning of the program, which also includes the basis of the fuselage.

Comment: @Adnan Great idea. I tried that with `«` earlier without much luck. This is much better though.

Comment: Removing `U` and replacing `X` with `s` also saves a byte :).

Comment: @Adnan: yep, was just looking at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
;”_“|“|¶”jÐ€“  |¶“/_\¶”;K;“/___\¶ VvV
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KAnV_igJx84oCcfMK24oCdasOQ4oKs4oCcICB8wrbigJwvX1zCtuKAnTtLO-KAnC9fX19cwrYgVnZW&input=&args=IkNvZGUgR29sZiI)

Same idea as with my Pyth answer, but this can probably be golfed.

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, <strike>83</strike>, 92 bytes

<strike>`function f(x)return'  |\n /_\\\n'..x:gsub('(.)',' |%1|\n')..' |_|\n/___\\\n VvV'end`</strike>

```
print('  |\n /_\\\n'..(arg[1] and arg[1]:gsub('(.)',' |%1|\n') or '')..' |_|\n/___\\\n VvV')
```

Comment: If I add no input to your answer. It does not work.

Answer (score 3):

## Gema, 50 characters

```
\A=  |\n\ /_\\\n
?=\ |?|\n
\Z=\ |_|\n/___\\\n\ VvV
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n gema | gema '\A=  |\n\ /_\\\n;?=\ |?|\n;\Z=\ |_|\n/___\\\n\ VvV'
  |
 /_\
 |g|
 |e|
 |m|
 |a|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Comment: You're missing the ` |_|` before the base of the rocket I think

Comment: Ouch. Dumb miss. Thank you @TheLethalCoder.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a new (to me) (non-golfing) language.

Answer (score 3):

## BASH <strike>84</strike> 70

Saved 14 thanks to manatwork

```
(cat&&echo _)|sed 's~.~ |&|\n~g;1s~^~  |\n /_\\\n~;$s~$~/___\\\n VvV~'
```

Over half of the bytes are for adding the nose, and engine.

Comment: Why the `grep`?  `(cat&&echo _)|sed 's~.~ |&|\n~g;1s~^~  |\n /_\\\n~;$s~$~/___\\\n VvV~'`. Actually I see no reason to use `cat` and `echo` either. Would be shorter transformed into pure `sed` solution.

Comment: With pure sed, you don't get any output if you don't have input

Comment: Doh. You are right. Sorry, I forgot that part of requirement.

Comment: @manatwork I forgot about it in my first try too.

Comment: For future reference, avoid using <pre><code> tags. Use 4 spaces preceding the code in the future, as this auto-escapes Markdown formatting. I have maintained the current formatting due to the strikethrough, but you can just leave that in edit history as well for those curious to look at it.

Comment: @Syxer Thanks! I wasn't sure what the standard was in regards to striking or just removing.

Comment: Additionally if you keep the solution alone in its code block, [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) and similar scripts can insert correct length beside it. For example saying your code has 71 characters – you forgot to remove the ``\`` added by Syxer to avoid `_` being interpreted as italic markdown.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 94 bytes

```
@(s)char(['  |';' /_\';arrayfun(@(x)[' |' x '|'],s,'UniformOutput',0)';' |_|';'/___\';' VvV'])
```

Anonymous function

Comment: Not sure about MATLAB, but in Octave you can replace `false` with `0` to save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, <del>61</del> 51 bytes

My first code golf, I hope it is good enough.

```
"  |
 /_\\
"\1/.,{" |"\(\"|
"\}\*" |_|
/___\\
 VvV"
```

#### Explanation

```
"  |\n /_\\\n"   # Push the rocket's head
\                # Swap the head with the user's string
1/               # The string is converted into an array
.,               # Push array length
{" |"\           # Push the rocket's body and swap
(\               # Array's first element cut out
"|\n"\           # Push rocket's body and swap
}\*              # Repeat for array length times
" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV" # Push rocket's bottom
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IiAgfAogL19cXAoiXDEvLix7IiB8IlwoXCJ8CiJcfVwqIiB8X3wKL19fX1xcCiBWdlYi&input=RWFydGg&args=)

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

Here the `<End>` is literally the "End" key.

```
i <End>_:s/./ |&|\r/g
/___\
 VvVggxo /_\
```

Unprintables so:

```
i <End>_^O:s/./ |&|\r/g
/___\
 VvV^[ggxo /_\^[
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
↷¦|_θ__←v↖V→/↑_↑⊕Ｌθ/‖Ｂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R2/ZDy2riz@2Ij3/UNqHsUdu0sEdtk/QftU0E8ic@6pr6fs@aczv0HzVMe79n0f//CiDABQA)

Needs trailing newline in input, due to how Charcoal input works.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <strike>47</strike> <strike>46</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>37</strike> 35 bytes

```
A_Ó./ |&|\r
a/___\
 VvVHO  |
 /_\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3zFe@vBkPX2FGrWamCKuRP34@PgYLoWwsjBpD38FhRouBf34mP//M1JzcvIVyvOLclIA)

This is my first time trying to golf something. There is probably room for improvement since I don't know V, only vim.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 415f 1bf3 2e2f 207c 267c 5c72 2f67 0a61  A_.../ |&|\r/g.a
00000010: 2f5f 5f5f 5c0a 2056 7656 1b48 4f20 207c  /___\. VvV.HO  |
00000020: 0a20 2f5f 5c                             . /_\
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Excel 2016+, 73 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the calling cell

```
="  |
 /_\
 |"&Concat(Mid(A1,Sequence(Len(A1)),1)&"|
 |")&"_|
/___\
 VvV"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```
`|/__`:ḣṫ⁰p\|vp÷„Ḣ‛VvWøM
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwiYHwvX19gOuG4o+G5q+KBsHBcXHx2cMO34oCe4bii4oCbVnZXw7hNIiwiIiwiRWFydGgiXQ==)

*-5 bytes thanks to allxy*

### How?

```
`|/__`:ḣṫ⁰p\|vp÷„Ḣ‛VvWøM
`|/__`                     # Push string "|/__"
      :                    # Duplicate
       ḣ                   # Head extract, push a[0] and a[1:]
        ṫ                  # Tail extract, push a[:-1] and a[-1] (stack: a[0], a[1:-1], a[-1])
         ⁰p                # Prepend the input to this a[-1]
           \|vp            # For each character, prepend "|"
               ÷           # Dump, push all contents to the stack
                „          # Rotate stack left once
                 Ḣ         # Remove head
                  ‛Vv      # Push string "Vv"
                     W     # Wrap stack into a list
                      øM   # Flip brackets and palindromise each
                           # C flag centers and joins on newlines
```

Comment: [28](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgfC9fX2A64bij4bmr4oGwcGZcXHx2cMO34oCe4bii4oCbVnZXw7hNw7jEiuKBiyIsIiIsIkVhcnRoIl0=) and you can save more with the `C` flag.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>128</s> <s>97</s> 94 bytes

```
#define P printf(
r(char*s){for(P"  |\n /_\\\n");*s;P" |%c|\n",*s++));P" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");}
```

Un-golfed:

```
#define P printf(
/* Knock off a few bytes by abusing the preprocessor */

r(char*s) { /* Function r (for rocket) accepting a string */
    for( /* For loop */
        P "  |\n /_\\\n"); /* BEFORE entering loop, print the top part */
        *s; /* Loop until the null at the end of the string is encountered */
        P " |%c|\n",*s++) /* Print a middle section for each char */
    );
    P " |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"); /* Print the bottom part */
}
```

After realizing that I have completely forgotten about `puts()` due to its usual uselessness (I always use `printf()`), I finally got it under 90 bytes, only to realize that someone else had beaten me to it:

```
r(char*s){for(puts("  |\n /_\\");*s;printf(" |%c|\n",*s++));puts(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 38 bytes

```
j++"  |
 /_\\"jR_B" |"+Q\_"/___\\
 VvV
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B%2B%22++%7C%0A+%2F_%5C%5C%22jR_B%22+%7C%22%2BQ%5C_%22%2F___%5C%5C%0A+VvV&input=%22Earth%22&test_suite_input=%22Earth%22%0A%22%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22%7C0%22%0A%22%5C%2F%5C%5C%22%0A%22_+_+%22%0A%22SPACEY%22&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B%2B%22++%7C%0A+%2F_%5C%5C%22jR_B%22+%7C%22%2BQ%5C_%22%2F___%5C%5C%0A+VvV&input=%22Earth%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Earth%22%0A%22%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22%7C0%22%0A%22%5C%2F%5C%5C%22%0A%22_+_+%22%0A%22SPACEY%22&debug=0)

Comment: Also 38 bytes: [`%."
|¼v¤<½ózÓa9Êh"jXL2" ||"+z\_`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25.%22%0A%7C%12%C2%BC%C2%86v%C2%A4%3C%15%C2%9B%C2%BD%C3%B3%11%C2%88z%C3%93%C2%82a9%C3%8Ah%22jXL2%22+%7C%7C%22%2Bz%5C_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Earth%0A%0Aa%0A%7C0%0A%5C%2F%5C%0A+_+_+%0A++++%0ASPACEY&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <strike>97 94</strike> 77 bytes

```
print("  |\n /_\\\n"+args(0).map{" |"+_+"|\n"}.mkString+" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3, <s>78</s> 75 Bytes**

```
w="  |\n /_\\"
for i in input(): w+="\n |"+i+"|"
w+="\n |_| \n/___\\ \n VvV"
print(w)
```

Thanks @ValueInk for spotting that I could lose 3 bytes by clearing the `input` function of arguments.

Comment: Asking adding a character to print when asking for input `input(">")` is wholly unnecessary and you could save bytes by just calling `input()`

Comment: @ValueInk thanks, I had forgotten that you could leave the `input` command blank.

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, 68 bytes

```
{"""  |
 /_\${it.replace(Regex("."),"\n |\$0|")}
 |_|
/___\
 VvV"""}
```

Pretty straightforward. Uses multiline string and a regex replacement. This is a lambda with `(String)->String` type. Test:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val function : (String)->String = {"""  |
 /_\${it.replace(Regex("."),"\n |\$0|")}
 |_|
/___\
 VvV"""}
    println(function(" _ _ "))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), <s>157 154</s> 143 bytes

```
pL   |
def p print : lbl L Line
pL  /_\
loadL :
a = 256
:a
x = get a
if x c
GOTO e
:c
p  |
pChar x
pL |
a + 1
if x a
:e
pL  |_|
pL /___\
p  VvV
```

It should be fairly readable. Feel free to [try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cEwgICB8CmRlZiBwIHByaW50IDogbGJsIEwgTGluZQpwTCAgL19cCmxvYWRMIDoKYSA9IDI1Ngo6YQp4ID0gZ2V0IGEKaWYgeCBjCkdPVE8gZQo6YwpwICB8CnBDaGFyIHgKcEwgfAphICsgMQppZiB4IGEKOmUKcEwgIHxffApwTCAvX19fXApwICBWdlY&input=&args=Uy5JLkwuTy5T)

Comment: @LeakyNun :( just out of curiosity how can you see null bytes so I can self-debug next time.

Comment: @LeakyNun oh ok, I found the issue. Its all fixed up now

Comment: [143 bytes](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cEwgICB8CmRlZiBwIHByaW50IDogbGJsIEwgTGluZQpwTCAgL19cCmxvYWRMIDoKYSA9IDI1Ngo6YQp4ID0gZ2V0IGEKaWYgeCBjCkdPVE8gZQo6YwpwICB8CnBDaGFyIHgKcEwgfAphICsgMQppZiB4IGEKOmUKcEwgIHxffApwTCAvX19fXApwICBWdlY&input=&args=Uy5JLkwuTy5T)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 116 bytes

**Golfed**

```
write(c("  |"," /_\\",sapply(strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]],function(y)paste0(" |",y,"|"))," |_|","/___\\"," VvV"),1,1)
```

**Ungolfed**

```
write(                                             # Write to console
      x = c("  |"," /_\\",                         # Add in stock rocket part  
        sapply(X = strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]],    # Take in rocket part specification, split string, loop over all specs
               FUN = function(y) {                 
                 paste0(" |",y,"|"))               # Custom build rocket body
                },
        " |_|","/___\\"," VvV"),                   # Add stock parts  
      file = 1,                                    # Print to console
      ncolumns = 1)

  |
 /_\
 |s|
 |t|
 |r|
 |s|
 |p|
 |l|
 |i|
 |t|
 |!|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 2):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>54</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

This was my first answer to a challenge on this site. The solution is simple, mainly printing, so I spent some time making sure that it can't be golfed anymore.

```sed
s:.:\n |&|:g
s::  |& /_\\&:
a\ |_|\n/___\\\n VvV
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@19spWcVk6dQo1Zjlc5VbGWlAGQq6MfHxKhZcSXGKNTE18Tk6cfHAwWAqsLKwv7/93MMdgQA)**

Fast forward half a year later, I rewrote the script, used a trick for good measure and golfed it down to 1 byte shorter. Now that's progress!

**Explanation:** the pattern space at each step is mentioned for clarity, given the input example "GO"

```sed
s:.:\n |&|:g
   # turn each input char into a section of the rocket (\n |G|\n |O|)
s::  |& /_\\&:
   # 's::' is a trick; the search part is actually the one from the previous 's'
   #command, i.e. a char. Only the first char, '\n', the modifier 'g' is not
   #inherited. The replace part is the head of the rocket. (  |\n /_\\n |G|\n |O|)
a\ |_|\n/___\\\n VvV
   # append the tail of the rocket, plus implicit printing at the end

  |
 /_\
 |G|
 |O|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <strike>69</strike> 68 bytes

```
print([[  |
 /_\
]]..(...):gsub('.',' |%0|\n')..[[ |_|
/___\
 VvV]])
```

Should work with Lua 5.1 - 5.3 (tested with 5.3).

I don't have enough rep to comment on nolan's answer, but this is quite similar.

I'm using `[[long string]]` syntax to save a few bytes by avoiding needing to escape newlines and backslashes.

`gsub` doesn't need to specify a capture because `%0` can be used. (Actually, `%1` still works without a capture as well, but this isn't strictly documented.)

I also trimmed away the input validation; not sure why it was there -- an empty string input (as opposed to empty input) will work fine. Handling a missing `arg[1]` can be done more briefly just by `(arg[1]or''):gsub(...)` anyway, although at this point it is briefer just to switch to `io.read()` and get the input from stdin. Anyway, `...` is a shorter way to get command-line input (even if parens are needed).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 51 bytes

```
{"  |
 /_\\
 {("|$_|
"for |.comb,'_')}/___\\
 VvV"}
```

A lambda that takes a string as argument, and returns a string.

[try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/ehvqs6hxl2)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 101 bytes

This is an improvement on [Frédéric's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91275/59052). I eliminated the variable definition, the for-loop, and the need for the `sep=""` argument.

```
cat("  |\n /_\\\n",sapply(strsplit(scan(,""),""),function(x)paste0("|",x,"|\n")),"|_|\n/___\\\n VvV")
```

Ungolfed:

```
cat("  |\n /_\\\n",                      # Print top of rocket
    sapply(
      strsplit(scan(,""),""),            # Take stdin and convert to list of chars
      function(x)paste0("|",x,"|\n")),   # Print letters
    ,"|_|\n/___\\\n VvV")                # Print bottom and FLAMES
```

I'm sure that there is still some improvement possible.

Comment: Needs `"  |\n /_\\\n"`, but never thought about hard coding `\n`

Comment: @Vlo Thanks, that's fixed now. (It is correct in my ungolfed/explained version, so I must have just pasted the wrong version in the first instance. The byte count is unchanged, thankfully.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 50 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
↑'/___\' ' VvV',⍨'  |' ' /_\',↓' ','|',⍨'|',⍪⍞,'_'
```

OK, so it may not be the shortest submission, but it *is* the only one that carries the name of [a real rocket manufacturer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_Physics_Laboratory):

```apl
  |  
 /_\ 
 |A| 
 |P| 
 |L| 
 |_| 
/___\
 VvV
```

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2191%27/___%5C%27%20%27%20VvV%27%2C%u2368%27%20%20%7C%27%20%27%20/_%5C%27%2C%u2193%27%20%27%2C%27%7C%27%2C%u2368%27%7C%27%2C%u236A%u2375%2C%27_%27%7D%A8%27%27%20%27a%27%20%27%7C0%27%20%27%5C/%5C%27%20%27%20_%20_%20%27%20%27%20%20%20%20%27%20%27SPACEY%27&run)

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 60 bytes

```
'  |'a' /_\'av
a$v?(0:i'|| '<
'r\~'_'$a'/___\'a' VvV
 o>l?!;
```

Pretty simple really. lots of strings, the newlines are annoying.

[Try it online](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/Zh3YMSH3Ba2vWGvWo)

```
  |
 /_\
 |>|
 |<|
 |>|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, 99 byte

```
let f:(String)->String={$0.characters.reduce("  |\n /_\\\n"){$0+" |\($1)|\n"}+" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"}
```

Use like this:

```
print(f("Some String"))
```

Result:

```
  |
 /_\
 |S|
 |o|
 |m|
 |e|
 | |
 |S|
 |t|
 |r|
 |i|
 |n|
 |g|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 51 bytes

**50 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```pl
s/./$&|
 |/g;s~^~  |
 /_\\
 |~;s~$~_|
/___\\
 VvV~
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -pe 's/./$&|
 |/g;s~^~  |
 /_\\
 |~;s~$~_|
/___\\
 VvV~' <<< earth
  |
 /_\
 |e|
 |a|
 |r|
 |t|
 |h|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

```
perl -pe 's/./$&|
 |/g;s~^~  |
 /_\\
 |~;s~$~_|
/___\\
 VvV~' <<< ''
  |
 /_\
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

```
perl -pe 's/./$&|
 |/g;s~^~  |
 /_\\
 |~;s~$~_|
/___\\
 VvV~' <<< '0|'
  |
 /_\
 |0|
 |||
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dart, 80 bytes

```
g(s)=>'  |\n /_\\\n${s.split('').map((s)=>' |$s|\n').join()} |_|\n/___\\\n VvV';
```

Running it through

```
main()=>print(g("Jasper"));
```

Gives:

```
  |
 /_\
 |J|
 |a|
 |s|
 |p|
 |e|
 |r|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 38 bytes

```
"  |
 /_\
 |"q'_+"|
 |"*"|
/___\
 VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@koFDDpaAfH8OlUKNUqB6vrVQDYmkBKf34eJBwWFmY0v//NQYA)

**Explanation**

Nothing fancy, pretty straightforward.

```
"  |\n /_\\n |"                              Push the top of the rocket
               q'_+                          Push the input and append an underscore
                   "|\n |"*                  Join the characters of the input with the sides
                           "|\n/___\\n VvV"  Push the bottom of the rocket
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>85</s> 74 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(format t"  |
 /_\\
~{ |~a|
~} |_|
/___\\
 VvV"(coerce s'list)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoAgDADAnVc0XWwnX@EXmEhIRY0mGgwQFytfR11vuLBv@WyNaJdjnIQy0xLTIQUKAqiB3jtn6g1aRU19QL2a3vtfwV4WKcQ5hRly902FmXGQVFbk1l4)(I added some bytes to call this anonymous function)

For changing part we take input as string.

```
~{ |~a|         ;we loop through all characters of string
    ~}          ;printing characters from list
(coerce s'list) ;string is converted into list of characters later used by above loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 52 characters

```
?(\|'\| \
)\\\_\/ \
\|  ^\
 \|\_\|\
\/\_\_\_\\\
 VvV
```

Only tricky point is that Keg has no strings, the input is pushed to stack character by character. So the processing order is: read input (`?`) and turn it into middle section, append top section reversed, reverse them all (`^`), append bottom section.

(Note that the interpreter (TIO implementation?) does not support absolutely no input. Empty input is specified as single newline, which will not be processed anyway.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run./##y05N///fXiOmRj2mRiGGSzMmJiY@Rh/IAnIV4mK4FGJqgAI1QL4@kAbBGKBgWFnY//@uiUUlGQA)

Answer (score 2):

## C - 84 Bytes

```
f(char*s){puts("  |\n /_\\");while(*s)printf(" |%c|\n", *s++);puts(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
f(char* s)
{
    puts("  |\n /_\\");

    while(*s)
        printf(" |%c|\n", *s++);

    puts(" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV");
}
```

**Explanation**

Function that receives a string prints it into the ascii-rocket. Tested on GCC, generates some warnings if not compiled with -std=c89.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ù  |ÿ /_\è'_▐û |\+mñn'/ÿ___\+ÿ VvV]n
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wTgWFmsP7FfTjYw6vUI9/NG3C4d0KNTHauYc35qnrH94fHx8fow2UDysLi837/1/dVV1HPRGIi4C4BIgz1Lm4gAJc6jVAjgGQjokBMvSBGMjgUlcAMuKBGEFDxBCYSz0YSAcAsSMQOwMxyIpIdQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ù  |          # Push string "  |"
ÿ /_\         # Push string " /_\"
è             # Push the inputs as string-array
 '_▐         '# Append a trailing "_"
    û |\+     # Prepend " |" in front of each string
         mñ   # Palindromize each string in the list
           n  # Join it with newline delimiter
'/           '# Push string "/"
  ÿ___\       # Append string "___\": "/___\"
ÿ VvV         # Push string " VvV"
]             # Wrap the entire stack into a list
 n            # Join it with newline delimiter
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>65</s> 60 bytes

```
`0:"  |\n /_\\";{`0:" |",x,"|"}'$1:0;`0:" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJwrtjKwMrBOMLBSUlCoiclT0I+PiVGyrgYL1CjpVOgo1SjVqqtoFUPU1MQDFenHxwNVARWHlYUpAQBBrRJs)

-5 bytes thanks to Razetime!

First ever K answer! May not be perfect, but it's pretty good!

Explaination:

```
`0:"  |\n /_\\" / Print the top of the rocket
{`0:" |",x,"|"} / Print " |$x|"
'$1:0; / For each character in the user input
/ Note: ';' is important because without it
/ the console will also output `(:: :: ...)`
`0:" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV" / Print the end of the rocket
```

Comment: since `s` is only used once, you can inline it: [try it!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLMLBSUlCoiclT0I+PiVGyrk4ACdQo6VToKNUo1aqrGFoZWEPE4oGq9OPjgcqAqsPKwpQA67gQ6A==) Also, `0:`  returns a list of lines, while `1:` returns a single string. I've changed that as well.

Comment: good job on your first K answer. I will try and give a few more golfing suggestions later.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>67 63</s> 59 bytes

```haskell
(++"_|\n/___\\\n VvV").("  |\n /_\\\n |"++).(>>=(:"|\n |"))
```

Thanks to Damien it's now essentially the same as xnor's answer, just in point-free notation. [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/MYt2Mh)

Comment: I never use `concatMap`. You should use `>>=` or `=<<`instead. `concatMap f s` is the same as `f=<<s` or `s>>=f`

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>130</s> <s>111</s> 95 bytes

```
s=>{var a="  |\n /_\\\n";foreach(var c in s)a+=" |"+c+"|\n";a+=" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV";return a;};
```

*Saved 16 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

Comment: Trailing whitespaces are optional, so `a="  |  \n";` can be `a="  |\n";`. Same applies to a few other lines. Also, why the `a+="111";a+="222";a+="333";`? You can just do this once: `a+="111222333";`. Total becomes: `s=>{var a="  |\n  /_\\\n";for(int i=0;i<s.Length;)a+=" |"+s[i++]+"|\n";return a+" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV";};` (**103 bytes**) Also, I'm not entirely sure, but isn't a foreach with characters shorter than your for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 128 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=%1_
echo   ^|
echo  /_\
:l
echo  ^|%s:~0,1%^|
set s=%s:~1%
if not "%s%"=="" goto l
echo /___\
echo  VvV
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (using external lib - Enumerable) (84 bytes)

```
n=>" |\n /_\\\n"+_.From(n).WriteLine(x=>" |"+x+"|")+(n?"\n":'')+" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: Pretty straight forward. Just boilerplates the rocketship template (top and bottom), and concats the fuselage string in the middle. Whats eating up a lot of bytes is the check if the input is truthy, because for an empty string it's wrong to add a newline to the beginning of the bottom template

I love how the native JS answer blows this away...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>65</s> 60 bytes

```
say'  |
 /_\\';say" |$_|"for split'',<>;say' |_|
/___\
 VvV'
```

Needs -E to use say, input should be piped in in order to not have a trailing newline. Notice that there's a space at the beginning of the second and fourth lines. Takes advantage of being able to use literal new lines in Perl to save a byte over using \n in each of the cases

Thanks to @manatwork for saving 5 bytes!

Comment: I'm afraid you did the same mistake as [I did](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91182/this-isnt-rocket-science?page=1&tab=votes#comment222355_91244) – you forgot the `|_|`.

Comment: @manatwork Nope! the s/\n/_/ adds it in since input in Perl comes with a new line character at the end, I'm swapping it for the underscore and it's handled as an additional character in the loop

Comment: Strange. I get the output without it: http://pastebin.com/QB2qMuSE Oh, I see, this is newline dependent. As  the question owner wrote that will be no newline in input, I tried without.

Comment: Oh! Instead of piping in the input, execute the file and then type the input (followed by pressing enter to end the input). The enter from that is what gets translated to the _. Alternately, replace the first newline with $ in order to be able to pipe in input (but not enter it manually) for the same byte count

Comment: Interesting choice, given it would be shorter without that newline handling: http://pastebin.com/QXRFdJwU

Comment: I guess I've just always assumed that passing input had to be done manually and I was forced to deal with the new line. If I'm allowed to use echo to pass it in though, that's definitely the better solution

Answer (score 1):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript), 76 bytes

```
{s|"  |
 /_\\
"+(s as Array):map({e|" |"+e+"|
"}):fuse()+" |_|
/___\\
 VvV"}
```

`{s|...}` declare a lambda and `as` is the casting operator.

Answer (score 1):

**MUMPS: 94 bytes**

To get some more variety in here. I tried to solve this in C by declaring main as an array of integers that were compiled machine code but it was still too big, especially on a 64 bit machine.

```
r
 r x w !,"  |",!," /_\",! f i=1:1:$L(x) w " |",$E(x,i),"|",!
 w " |_|",!,"/___\",!," VvV" q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>47</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
95h"' |'@yPhh]v'   /|_ \'2ew'/ _V_v_V\'2e
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OTVoIicgfCdAeVBoaF12JyAgIC98XyBcJzJldycvIF9WX3ZfVlwnMmU&input=J0VhcnRoJw)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure (83 bytes)

```
#(str "  |\n /_\\\n |" (clojure.string/join "|\n |" (str % \_)) "|\n/___\\\n VvV")
```

And here's a rocket for you:

```
  |
 /_\
 |W|
 |e|
 |l|
 |c|
 |o|
 |m|
 |e|
 | |
 |t|
 |a|
 | |
 |E|
 |a|
 |r|
 |f|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES5), <strike>109</strike> 89 Bytes)

```
function(n){s=" |\n /_\\\n |";for(i=0;c=n[i++];)s+=c+"|\n |";return s+"_|\n/___\\\n VvV"}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function a(n){
var str="  |\n /_\\\n";
for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++){
str+=" |"+n[i]+"|\n";
}
return str+" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV";
}
```

EDIT: Saved 20 Bytes thanks to manatwork!

Comment: You have a small bug: the flame is not centered. That will cost you 1 character, but there are a couple of them you can remove: user shorter variable name; do not enclose the single instruction repeated by `for` in braces; increment the counter when you use it, instead of `for`'s 3rd parameter; rearrange the strings to use a single string literal in the loop; test whether string end is reached by current character, not by `.length`; and anonymous functions are acceptable: `function(n){s="  |\n /_\\\n |";for(i=0;c=n[i++];)s+=c+"|\n |";return s+"_|\n/___\\\n VvV"}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>132</s> <s>109</s> <s>107</s> 96 Bytes

```
i->"  |\n /_\\ \n"+i.chars().mapToObj(c->" |"+(char)c+"|")
                            .collect(joining("\n"))+"\n |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"
```

Comment: How do you run this? This doesn't seem to be a complete method...

Comment: @JopV. Yes it's a lambada expression, this is a `Function<String, String>` in Java-8 to be applied on any string value. Correct me if I have mistaken.

Comment: Your submission shouldn't have whitespace added (you can include a separate readable version with spaces). Also it looks like you're using a static import of `java.util.stream.Collectors.joining`, so that statement should be included in your submission and byte count. And please mention that lambda type in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 82 bytes

```
(display"  |\n /_\\\n")(for((i s))(printf" |~a|~n"i))(display" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV")
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (display "  |\n /_\\\n")
  (for((i s))
    (printf " |~a|~n"i))
  (display" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"))
```

Testing:

```
(f "Racket")
```

Output: A Rocket by Racket!

```
  |
 /_\
 |R|
 |a|
 |c|
 |k|
 |e|
 |t|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 83 Bytes

```
s=input("")
print("  | \n /_\\")
for c in s:print(" |"+c+"|")
print("/___\\\n VvV")
```

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8C2oCgzr8S6QENJQaFGISZPQT8@JkZJkystv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK1AKmpUi2uUVJM1uYAc/fh4oEqghrCyMCXN//9t7GAQAA).

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>102</s> <s>84</s></sub> 82 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate Window function that takes input of type `Variant/String` from cell `[A1]` and outputs a rocket to the VBE immdiate window

**Golfed:**

```vb
?"  |":?" /_\":For i=0To[Len(A1)]:?" |"Mid([A1&"_"],i+1,1)"|":Next:?"/___\":?" VvV
```

**Output:**

```vb
[A1]="NASA.XLSM"
?"  |":?" /_\":For i=0To[Len(A1)]:?" |"Mid([A1&"_"],i+1,1)"|":Next:?"/___\":?" VvV
  |             '  <- Output
 /_\
 |N|
 |A|
 |S|
 |A|
 |.|
 |X|
 |L|
 |S|
 |M|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 55+1 (-p flag)=56 bytes

```
s/(.)/\n |$1|/g;$_="  |  \n /_\\ $_ |_| \n/___\\\n VvV"
```

Takes string as a single line (with trailing newline) from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>27</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
yQŗ4δ⁾≥‘π0ρ9³‘OΓ,{Ƨ |ΚΓO
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=eVEldTAxNTc0JXUwM0I0JXUyMDdFJXUyMjY1JXUyMDE4JXUwM0MwMCV1MDNDMTklQjMldTIwMThPJXUwMzkzJTJDJTdCJXUwMUE3JTIwJTdDJXUwMzlBJXUwMzkzTw__,inputs=RWFydGglNUM_)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 27 bytes

```
S'|ì»"|
/_
ÿ
|_
/__
Vv".∞.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/WL3m8JpDu5VquPTjuQ7v56qJBzLiucLKlPQedczTS/7/PzEpGQA)

### Explanation

```
S          # Split input into seperate characters
 '|ì»      # Prepend '|' to each and join by newline
     "|    # Half the rocket, where 'ÿ' is replaced by the processed input
/_
ÿ
|_
/__
Vv"
   .∞.c    # Intersected mirror and centralize
```

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, <sub><s>61</s></sub> 59 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs a rocket to the calling cell

```
="  |
 /_\
"&RegExReplace(A1&"_","(.)"," |$1|
")&"/___\
 VvV
```

Example Output given `[A1]="Google`

```
  |
 /_\
 |G|
 |o|
 |o|
 |g|
 |l|
 |e|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 42 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
♀◘ááⁿ▄εá»▀▄84♀☺áⁿE►âD85♀►áⁿ▀ⁿ▄ε»▀▀▀▄▄εá╓÷╓
```

Explanation

```
♀◘ááⁿ▄εá»▀▄         # Push literal   |\n /_\
8                   # Print the first stack value, then a newline.
4                   # Enter an iteration block over the first stack value and push the iteration element register at the begining of each loop.
♀☺áⁿ                # Push literal  |
E                   # Push the difference of the second and first stack values.
►â                  # Push literal |
D                   # Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
8                   # Print the first stack value, then a newline.
5                   # End an iteration block.
♀►áⁿ▀ⁿ▄ε»▀▀▀▄▄εá╓÷╓ # Push literal  |_|\n/___\\n VvV
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.3/JstxGWT.html?code=4pmA4peYw6HDoeKBv%24KWhM61w6HCu%24KWgOKWhDg04pmA4pi6w6Higb9F4pa6w6JEODXimYDilrrDoeKBv%24KWgOKBv%24KWhM61wrviloDiloDiloDiloTiloTOtcOh4pWTw7filZM%3D&args=VGVzdA%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.7, <s>79</s> 77 Bytes

```
o='  | \n /_\\\n'
for c in input()+"_":o+=f' |{c}|\n'
print(o+'/___\\\n VvV')
```

-2 bytes thanks to Value Ink

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you can save 2 bytes by iterating through `input()+"_"` so you don't have to manually put in the bottom of the rocket shaft. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P99WXUGhRiEmT0E/PiYmJk@dKy2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0tZXilazytW3T1BVqqpNra0BqCooy80o08rXV9ePjwdoUwsrC1DX//y/KT85OLQEA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 77 bytes

```
select'  |
 /_\
'||regexp_replace(x,'(.)',' |\1|
')||' |_|
/___\
 VvV'from t;
```

It works with an assumption that input string is stored in a table t(x), e.g.

```
with t(x) as (select 'Earth' from dual)
```

Test in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> set pages 0
SQL> with t(x) as (select 'Earth' from dual)
  2  select'  |
  3   /_\
  4  '||regexp_replace(x,'(.)',' |\1|
  5  ')||' |_|
  6  /___\
  7   VvV'from t;
  |
 /_\
 |E|
 |a|
 |r|
 |t|
 |h|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>71</s> <s>69</s> <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```
f:"|"u:C95Ps.s.fP" /_\"Fi,#a{Ps.f.a@i.f}P" |_|"P"/___\"" VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/zUqpRqnUytnSNKBYr1gvLUBJQT8@RsktU0c5sRoolKaX6JCpl1YLFK@Jr1EKUNKPjwfKKymElYUp/f//PzWxqCQDAA)

[Try it online!][TIO-jyx4p3hj]

```
f:"|"
u:C95
a:q
Ps.s.f
P" /_\"
F i ,#a{
    Ps.f.a@i.f     make the fuselage
}
P" |_|"
P"/___\"
" VvV"
```

nothing fancy happening here.

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 159 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(string[]a){var f="";foreach (char c in a[0]){f+=" |"+c+"|\n";}System.Console.Write(@"  |
 /_\
"+f+@" |_|
/___\
 VvV");}}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zGnks6)

Comment: Suggest `foreach(var c in a[0])f+=" |"+c+"|\n";` instead of `foreach (char c in a[0]){f+=" |"+c+"|\n";}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```
puts"  |\n /_\\";gets.split('').append('_').each{|a|puts" |#{a}|"};puts"/___\\\n VvV"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN0MLSkuKlRQUamLyFPTjY2KUrNNTS4r1igtyMks01NU19RILClLzUjTU44Hs1MTkjOqaxBqInhrl6sTaGqVaazBXPz4eqB1oSlhZmBLEcKgdC5YFBzg6u0ZCeAA)

Comment: [70 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN90KSkuKlRQUargU9ONjYpSsNdJTS4r1kjMSi4ptbOzjNfVyEwuqIYpqlKvjDWtrlGqtwXz9-HigDi6FsLIwJYhpUEMXLAsOcHR2jYTwAA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 63

```
s=>`  |\n /_\\\n${(s+'_').replace(/./g," |$&|\n")}/___\\\n VvV`
```

executed using `s("test")` for example.

Answer (score 0):

## SpecBAS - 95 bytes

```
1 input a$: ?"  |"'" /_\"
2 for i=1 to len a$:? " |";a$(i);"|":next i
3 ?" |_|"'"/___\"'" VvV"
```

The apostrophe moves the cursor down a line, and `?` is shorthand for `PRINT`

Answer (score 0):

## R, 148 bytes

```
f=function(b){cat("  |\n /_\\\n |",paste(as.character(unlist(strsplit(c(b,"_"),''))),collapse='|\n |'),"|\n/___\\\n VvV",sep="")}
f(commandArgs(T))
```

If above code is in sample.R file then run from command line

```
Rscript sample.R "GOKUL"
```

**Output:**

```
  |
 /_\
 |G|
 |O|
 |K|
 |U|
 |L|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 0):

### GNU sed, 53 bytes

```
1i\  |\n /_\\
s:.: |&|\n:g;s:$: |_|:g;$a\/___\\\n VvV
```

With GNU sed, you can omit the initial \ for the a command, so it is one byte less:

```
1i\  |\n /_\\
s:.: |&|\n:g;s:$: |_|:g;$a/___\\\n VvV
```

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 51 bytes

```
s/$/_/
s/./ |&|\n/g
s!.*!  |\n /_\\\n&/___\\\n VvV!
```

Each line from stdin produces a new rocket on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

## Dart, <s>110</s> 106 bytes

```dart
r(var s){s=s+'_';var o='  |\n /_\\\n',i=0;while(i<s.length)o=o+' |'+s[i++]+'|\n';return o+'/___\\\n VvV';}
```

**[Try it out](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ddce45019ab6fdf4dc6168bd8f4cfb44)**

*EDIT: Saved 4 bytes, thanks!*

Comment: Do not declare i separately as `int`, just enumerate it at `var`.

Comment: @manatwork What do you mean? How would you not have to declare `i`?

Comment: You have, but `var` is fine for i too: `var o='  |\n /_\\\n',i=0`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't know Dart had that!

Answer (score 0):

### dc, 55 bytes

Building a rocket with the **d**esck **c**alculator:

```dc
?[  |
 /_\
]n[[ |]nn[|
]nz0<R]sRz0!=R[ |_|
/___\
 VvV]p
```

Because dc interprets input as commands, our string's characters are assumed to be already on the stack and the code is acting more like a function accessing its arguments.

**Example run:**

```sh
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ dc -f rocket_science.dc
[A][S][A][N] #the stack is LIFO, so the arguments (characters) are in reverse order
  |
 /_\
 |N|
 |A|
 |S|
 |A|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 59 Bytes

```
'  |
 /_\' p '.' ' |%1|
' R "
$" '' R p ' |_|
/___\
 VvV' p
```

### Explination

```
'  |        #
 /_\'       # Build the top of the rocket
p           # Print it.
            # Input is taken implicitly.
'.' ' |%1|  # v
' R         # Replace each character with " |ITSELF|" followed by a newline.
"           # v
$" '' R  # Snip the last newline.
p           # Print the new body.
            #
' |_|       #
/___\       #
 VvV'       # Build the lower segment.
 p          # Print.
```

[Try it Online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=%27%20%20%7C%0A%20%2F_%5C%27%20p%20%27.%27%20%27%20%7C%251%7C%0A%27%20R%20%22%0A%24%22%20%27%27%20R%20p%20%27%20%7C_%7C%0A%2F___%5C%0A%20VvV%27%20p&input=%22Hello%2C%20World!%22)

Answer (score 0):

## Crystal, 89 bytes

```
x=gets.to_s.chomp;y="  |
 /_\\
";x.each_char{|c|y+=" |#{c}|
"};puts y+" |_|
/___\\
 VvV"
```

Ungolfed:

```ruby
input = gets
if !input
  STDERR.puts "Couldn't get input from stdin!"
  exit 1
end
puts <<-'END'
  |
 /_\
END
input.chomp.each_char do |char|
  puts " |#{char}|\n"
end
puts <<-'END'
/___\
 VvV
END
```

Example usage

Input: `Hello, world!`

Output:

```
  |
 /_\
 |H|
 |e|
 |l|
 |l|
 |o|
 |,|
 | |
 |w|
 |o|
 |r|
 |l|
 |d|
 |!|
 |_|
/___\
 VvV
```

- Actual newlines instead of `\n` to save 1 byte per newline
- `String#each_char` instead of `String#chars.each` to save 1 byte
- Temporary `y` variable instead of multiple `puts` calls to save a few bytes
- As Crystal is statically typed and `gets` can return `nil`, I had to find a way to workaround that. `not_nil!` raises an exception on runtime if the value is `nil` and otherwise just returns it, however, the `Nil` class also implements `to_s` (that returns a 0-length string) which is 4 characters (as opposed to 8). String also implements `to_s` (just returns itself), so this is a 4 characters shorter way to shut the compiler up.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 44 bytes

```
js[c2"  |  /_\\"m:" |_|"\_dzc3" |_| /___\ VvV
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=js%5Bc2%22++%7C++%2F_%5C%5C%22m%3A%22+%7C_%7C%22%5C_dzc3%22+%7C_%7C+%2F___%5C+VvV&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>47</s> 46 + 1 (`-n`) = 47 bytes

```perl
s/./ |$&|
/g;say"  |
 /_\\
$_ |_|
/___\\
 VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09foUZFrYZLP926OLFSSUGhhktBPz4mhkslXqEmHigeHw/iKYSVhSn9/x8c4Ojs@i@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BocF/3TwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 47 bytes

```
"  |
 /_\\"," |\((./"")[])|"," |_|
/___\\
 VvV"
```

Expanded

```
 "  |
  /_\\"             # Head

," |\((./"")[])|"   # Expand |x| with \(interpolation) for each
                    # value from (./"") split of input string by ""
," |_|
 /___\\
  VvV"              # Tail
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxDYAgEEDRnikuV0EiMoUr2IghdGIIKII2N7snsXz/7yfj5EvdkBgBSIBx1uKAQFbK0SCqZVX0B0fCONe3gPmekfnNRw05Xax1ajHqkI5WO4p/dG614wM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
->s{'  |
 /_\
 |'+(s+?_).chars*'|
 |'+'|
/___\
 VvV'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3dCsIwDEbv@xShN1FbV19Ah8juBWEg6yh1P/RKpd0cYn322tkl8J1DEogdb@/Q78P24D4I4AkIJQl4ZCvHcrXOGqOt26D/zyKEUvNB@SrxGyoCQAttB0P5rCl1gt8lSimkTAoq9qKxkl3Ox1NxpaTOOt0YaB/gp/gOnuPgACmyicXkiLyvpnpZkO7ekvAD)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>52 46</s> 45 bytes

```
2 4|.'___\/','VvV',' |','/_\','|'(,.,.[),&'_'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FIwaRGTz0@Pj5GX11HPawsDEgq1AAJ/fgYIFmjrqGjp6MXramjph6v/j81OSNfIU1BXZ0LzILRQBG//BIF18Sikgz1/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 51 bytes

xxd-style hexdump:

```
00000000: 56d8 8100 d7d0 80c3 cf20 5da3 7800 2080  VØ..×Ð.ÃÏ ]£x. .
00000010: 7b56 5881 0158 8102 a0a0 fc8a a0af dfdc  {VX..X..  ü. ¯ßÜ
00000020: 8aa0 7cfc 8aa0 7cfc 8aaf dfdf dfdc 8aa0  . |ü. |ü.¯ßßßÜ. 
00000030: d6f6 56                                  ÖöV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xDgIxDAR7XrFPcBI5seh5iM8@i4oC8f9gcmlwtdLMyMeprzlp3x3cXSCFCD6cIGQNFpXArg1DElQSul1@yWIc3MEiBVR4tRVKSggT/a2Ah9suahaiSYeF/a/lXfICu2hZeI/80YE5H/r@PL8)

### Equivalent JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

```
`  |
 /_\\
 |${[...a,'_'].join`|
 |`}|
/___\\
 VvV`
```

#### Explanation

A full program taking the implicit first line of input as `a`, it pushes the string `'_'` onto the array to build the last section of the fuselage. This answer is essentially a compilation of [edc65's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91199/42091) into Bean.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 52 bytes

```
" ||"i:0(?\$a
__/"a$"_"~/>o<"  |"a" /_\"ar"VvV "a"\_
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0mhpkYp08pAwz5GJZErPl5fKVFFKV6pTt8u30ZJQaFGKVFJQT8@RimxSCmsLEwByI2J///fzsYOAA)

Adds everything to the stack before printing.

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 126 bytes

```
	OUTPUT('O',6)
	O ='  |'
	O =' /_\'
	S =INPUT '_'
R	S LEN(1) . X REM . S	:F(O)
	O =' |' X '|'	:(R)
O	O ='/___\'
	O =' vVv'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNERD3V9dx0yTi9NfwVZdQaFGHcrSj48BMoMVbD39gKoU1OPVuYKAXB9XPw1DTQU9hQiFIFdfIB3MaeWm4Q/TX6MOlFCvUee00gjS5PIHC@rHx4PNAisoCytT53L1c/n/PzjA0dk1kgsA)

Input requires a single trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 86 bytes

A script that takes input from STDIN and output to the console.

```vb
Input""s$
?"  |
 /_\\"
For i=0To Len(s$)?" |",Mid$(s$+"_",i+1,1),"|"Next
?"/___\
 VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESalYhcteSUGhhktBPz4mRonLLb9IIdPWICRfwSc1T6NYRRMoW6Ok45uZogLkaSvFK@lkahvqGGrqKNUo@aVWlAC168fHx8dwKYSVhSn9/@/nGOyoB7QDAA)

Comment: I think you can save three bytes by putting the entire for loop onto one line.

Comment: @JonathanFrech You are absolutely right - I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 130 bytes

```pascal
var s:string;c:char;begin writeln('  |'#10' /_\');read(s);for c in s do writeln(' |',c,'|');writeln(' |_|'#10'/___\'#10' VvV')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxCoMwEIDhVznocAZsbVcz5gU6OQkhvUQbkCh3Ype8exraxfXn49@ckFuu00alHI5Betk5pllTT2/H@hXmmODDcQ9LahAg4@VxR@jsiEpzcL4RpaeVgaBCAb@edMaWWsxVnpr9Lzpr6@M3G44BVUj@VgoYY55f)

Colouring doesn't work correctly because of `\'` :)

`#10` represents character with ascii code 10 which is a newline.

Basic program flow here: write the top of the rocket, read input, print a row for each character in input [(`for ... in` loop added by FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu59.html), write the bottom of the rocket.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 46 + 3 (`-nlF` flag) = 49 bytes

```
say'  |
 /_\
',(map" |$_|
",@F,_),'/___\
 VvV'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJdQaGGS0E/PoZLXUcjN7FASaFGJb6GS0nHwU0nXlNHXT8@HiinEFYWpg5UX5CYnMqlEA@E//ILSjLz84r/6@bluP3X9TXVMzA0AAA).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'|„/_©¤IìS'|ì`®¤«„Vv».º.c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX//yd84oCeL1/CqcKkScOsUyd8w6xgwq7CpMKr4oCeVnbCuy7Cui5j//9Cb2I) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V/2X73mUcM8/fhDKw8tqTy8Jli95vCahEPrDi05tBooHlZ2aLfeoV16yf91Dm2z/x@t5JpYVJKhpKMERIlAXGMAJGJi9GNigLRCPBCCaCAAUsEBjs6ukUCGU36SUiwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'|      '# Push string "|"
„/_      # Push string "/_"
   ©     # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
¤        # Get the last character of this string (without popping the string itself): "_"
 Iì      # Prepend the input in front of this "_"
         #  i.e. "Bob" → "Bob_"
   S     # Convert it to a list of characters
         #  → ["B","o","b","_"]
    '|ì '# Prepend a "|" in front of each character
         #  → ["|B","|o","|b","|_"]
       ` # Push all those strings separated to the stack
®        # Push variable `®`: "/_"
 ¤«      # Append it's last character to itself: "/__"
„Vv      # Push string "Vv"
»        # Now join all strings on the stack by newlines
         #  → "|
         #     /_
         #     |B
         #     |o
         #     |b
         #     |_
         #     /__
         #     Vv"
 .º      # Intersected mirror this entire string (towards the right)
         #  → "|
         #     /_\
         #     |B|
         #     |o|
         #     |b|
         #     |_|
         #     /___\
         #     VvV"
   .c    # And then centralize the string (adding leading spaces where necessary)
         #  → "  |
         #      /_\
         #      |B|
         #      |o|
         #      |b|
         #      |_|
         #     /___\
         #      VvV"
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 133 bytes

```
	OUTPUT('O',6)
	O ='  |'
	O =' /_\'
	I =INPUT
S	I LEN(1) . X REM . I	:F(E)
	O =' |' X '|'	:(S)
E	O =' |_|'
	O ='/___\'
	O =' VvV'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNERD3V9dx0yTi9NfwVZdQaFGHcrSj48BMj0VbD39gKq4goFMH1c/DUNNBT2FCIUgV18g7clp5abhCtNbow6UUK9R57TSCNbkcoUKxsNM1I@PBxsJFg4rC1PncvVz@f8/OMDR2TUSAA)

Always funny to see the shape of the rocket in these answers.

Only interesting thing here is `OUTPUT('O',6)`, which sets `O` to be the `OUTPUT` variable into unit number 6, which is STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 81 bytes

```python
lambda x:"  |\n /_\\\n%s/___\\\n VvV"%''.join([" |%s|\n"%t for t in list(x+'_')])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEETP9iuWQNgExQjeCj2IeBeEgnRLqNhipKalDVIh/x6TzsC8OQwz/txrsMfQFRT65vN4NrDkDMCTBaWJyPJZab02KL8l44j792CsqBh4Pscd4w66YQIHxkJvZieWLWqUtQxtUSHuAJsU/uATSBElgo5eS1Ti7Xo6X@5YZ@nMpLM2zzbjZKwTnTBShj8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
æ¢ïÆn£╗ù♂»Σ√m3,^╝}.Σ8Æ╤º⌡
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=919b8b926e9cbb970bafe4fb6d332c5ebc7d2ee43892d1a7f5&i=%22%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22%7C0%22%0A%5C%2F%5C%0A%22+_+_+%22%0A%22++++%22%0A%22SPACEY%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## perl6 - 69

```
say "  |\n /-\\\n |{@*ARGS.comb.join("|\n |")}|\n |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"
```

Comment: Welcome! Consider adding an explanation of your program to those who may not understand it. Also consider adding a link to an online interpreter, such as [TIO](https://tio.run/#perl6). Code-only answers are usually automatically flagged as low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), <strike>75</strike> 69 bytes

-6 bytes because I remembered \n is a thing.

```
"  |\n /_\\"pi1bzst' | |'j[2ktNpNitclz1aztstcjz]" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"p
```

Try it online hopefully coming soon

Explanation:

```
"  |\n /_\\"pi                     | Print the first part of the rocket
-----------------------------------|
1bzs                               | Get the first command-line argument
            j[       clz1aztstcjz] | For each character in it
     t' | |'  2k                   | - Put it in the fuselage "| |"
                NpNi               | - If it is not null, print it (Null checking is due to the way loops work in 33)
-----------------------------------|
" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"p              | Print the bottom of the rocket
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 53 bytes

```
"  |\n /_\\"n@0$1/\;{" |"\"|\n"}/" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0lBoSYmT0E/PiZGKc/BQMVQP8a6WkmhRilGCSiuVKsPZMcDWfrx8UAlQJVhZWFK//@nJhaVZAAA)

```
"  |\n /_\\"n        ascii art
@                    rotate so input is on top
0$1/                 split input into elements of size 1
\;                   swap top elements, pop top (input)
{" |"\"|\n"}/        now the top element is the input array so for each we push the left pipe, swap, then push the right pipe
" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV" ascii art
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3, 86 bytes

code-golf:

```
n=input();print('  |\n / \ ')
for l in n:print(' |'+l+'|')
print(' |_|\n/___\ \n VvV')
```

normal:

````
n = input()
print('  |')
print(' / \')

for l in n:
    print(' |' + l + '|')

print(' |_|')
print('/___\')
print(' VvV')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 74 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS=".|";print"  |\n /_\\"}END{print" |_|\n/___\\\n VvV"}$0=" |"RT"|"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSa9GybqgKDOvRElBoSYmT0E/PiZGqdbVz6UaKloTDxTWj48HigOlw8rClGpVDGyB4kpBIUo1Sv//uyYWlWQAAA)

AWK was made for this kind of problem.

The `BEGIN` pattern do things before the input is read. Changing the default `RS` variable to `".|"` makes AWK read the input one character at a time (i.e., as the `/./` regex).

`RT` is exclusive to GNU AWK, being the text of the `RS` captured by the regex.

The `END` pattern do things after the input is finished.