# ASCII Airplane Banner

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Given two inputs -- one of them a non-empty printable ASCII string (including space, excluding newline), the other being one of two distinct, consistent values of your choice (`1 / 0`, `l / r`, `left / right`, etc.) -- output an ASCII art airplane banner of the string, pointing either left or right. For consistency, I'll be using `left` and `right` throughout this challenge description.

The plane is either `|-DI>-/` (`left`) or `\-<ID-|` (`right`). Since the banner is clear, it consists of the input string's characters separated by spaces, either left-to-right (`left`) or right-to-left (`right`), and surrounded by a box of the shape

```
    /--/
---<  <
    \--\
```

or

```
\--\
 >  >---
/--/
```

Note there must be one space between the beginning/end of the message and the `>`,`<` characters.

For example, here is the message `HAPPY BIRTHDAY!` and the direction `left`:

```
           /-------------------------------/
|-DI>-/---< H A P P Y   B I R T H D A Y ! <
           \-------------------------------\
```

Here is the message `PPCG` and the direction `right`. Note that the letters appear "backwards" when viewed from this side of the banner:

```
\---------\
 > G C P P >---\-<ID-|
/---------/
```

### Rules

- Leading or trailing newlines or whitespace are all optional, so long as the characters themselves line up correctly.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: [Slightly related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91182/9365)

Comment: JavaScript, 4 bytes: `eval` - Input a program that generates a left-facing plane for left, and a program that generates a right-facing plane for right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>149</s> 102 + 4 (`-plF` ) = <s>150</s> 106 bytes

*Shortened using tricks I've learned since the original answer.  Still scored using the rules in effect at the time of the question.*

```perl
s/./--/g;$_=$"x11 ."/-$_/";$_.="
|-DI>-/---< @F < 
".y|\\/|/\\|r;if(<>){y|<>|><|;$_=reverse;s|-/|-\\|}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCsIwFEDRvV8RQwcdXl4ydGoaRKTo4B8ESsFoC8WGpIjB568b63o5XO/CVOUcUSAA3uuya0r@UooJjlB2yNciGl4QHM8GVgOa7VumWcFFImuR0FoK9XjbarN7J9KGjKb/J7inC9HVkQAJVvXJ@dR7n9hhDMtw7dOmkN/ZL@P8iBkulZBKZvBT@wM)

Two line input. First is the message.  Second is 0 for left, 1 for right.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>141</s> 138 bytes

String and direction are input via currying syntax.
`'/\n|-DI>-/---< '` for left, `'/\n|-DI<-\\---> '` for right.

```
t=>p=>(r=`${s='           '}/${_='-'.repeat(t.length*2+1)}${p}${[...t].join` `} ${d=p[12]} 
${s}\\${_}\\`,d>'<'?[...r].reverse().join``:r)
```

```js
f=

t=>p=>(r=`${s='           '}/${_='-'.repeat(t.length*2+1)}${p}${[...t].join` `} ${d=p[12]} 
${s}\\${_}\\`,d>'<'?[...r].reverse().join``:r)

console.log(f('HAPPY BIRTHDAY!')('/\n|-DI>-/---< '))
console.log(f('HAPPY BIRTHDAY!')('/\n|-DI<-\\---> '))
```

Comment: Ha, hard coding a section of the output seems like an exploitation of a loophole, but it seems fine based on the challenge as written.  Clever!

Comment: @RickHitchcock The ultimate loophole is `eval`... just provide left and right function sources as your two values of your choice. (I thought there was a meta on this but I can't find it.)

Comment: @Neil The `eval` "trick" would be [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/42963) in spirit, even if not explicitly stated. This answer here is kinda clever, though.

Comment: Yeah, I was debating [whether to post `eval` as a serious answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/141025/revisions). A workaround for future challenges like this might be to include inputs as part of the byte count.

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>73</s>, 65 bytes

```
Ó./& 
É ÄÒ-ys$/YGpr\$.11>Hj|R|-DI>-/³-<A< ÀñkæG|æ}-r>$BR>³-\-<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BkPX01Ba7DnQqHWw5P0q0sVtGPdC8oilHRMzS088iqCarRdfG009U/tFnXRtrRRkH6cMPhjdmHl7nXHF4mVqtbZKfiFGQHlIzRtfn/PyDA2f2/IQA)

Not the greatest score, but that's because almost half of this comes from reversing the output.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: d32e 2f26 200a c920 c4d2 2d79 7324 2f59  ../& .. ..-ys$/Y
00000010: 4770 725c 242e 3131 3e48 6a7c 527c 2d44  Gpr\$.11>Hj|R|-D
00000020: 493e 2d2f b32d 3c1b 413c 201b c0f1 6be6  I>-/.-<.A< ...k.
00000030: 477c e616 7d2d 723e 2442 523e b32d 5c2d  G|..}-r>$BR>.-\-
00000040: 3c                                       <
```

Takes the string as input to the buffer, and the direction as `0` for left and `1` for right as command line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 63 bytes

```
„\\S'-¹g·>×ýD∞2äθ‚11ú"|-DI>-/---<"¸¹ε²i∞θ}J'<«S«ð«J¸«Àε²i∞2äθ}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcO8mJhgdd1DO9MPbbc7PP3wXpdHHfOMDi85t@NRwyxDw8O7lGp0XTztdPV1dXVtlA7tOLTz3NZDmzKBis7tqPVStzm0OvjQ6sMbDq32AsqtPtwAkwUbUXto9///AQHO7lwGAA)

Based off bugs that may get fixed in the future.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn possibly

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn actually no it won't work like that...

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Try to change the `0` on the second line to a `1`.

Comment: Ah, the leading space...

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>44</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
|-DI>-/³↗<→/-ＬηＬη↙¹←< ¿Ｎ↷⁴‖Ｔ⮌⪫η ‖Ｂ↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7RCoIwFIbvfYrh1QaJRV2pdFFCGBIi9QAmZ24wN5nTCHr3pVl6193hO/zf/5es0KUqhLWZ5tJg9@XFyd7zXRI6E9nOV3Brcl4xs0JutPyDH/O9BaYgK8MwI39IEKuHTIEO2c0CJ@BGaJRxinAim85cuvoOGhOCMt4r86nEO@KAaAHlQAWU5qoL2VKlazzbcuhBt4DPikvMBu1gHQd8E4fOGNBUPKctJLR27WTZ8WS9XrwB) Link is to verbose version of code. First input is 1 for right and 0 for left, second is banner string. Edit: <s>Saved 1 byte by using</s> `ReflectButterfly(:Up)` <s>as `ReflectButterfly(:Down)`</s> currently has a cursor positioning bug, but I saved a further 4 bytes by reversing the print direction, and now it doesn't matter which I use. <s>38</s> <s>34</s> 32 byte version if mirroring the banner was allowed:

```
|-DI>-/³Ｐ⪫⪫<<η ↘→\-ＬηＬη↖¹‖Ｂ↑¿Ｎ‖Ｔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxCsIwFEX3fkXIlECDiFtbHFSQSpVSdOtSS9IE0qTEpCL47zG2opvL493zzrstb0yrG@l9aYSyCD7JLl@TBcRpNJNV2I5OWjFM8aCFmgfMMhgDjmMAAcRvS48UJTt9V5XouP02JFMMWl2TX29BVWc54vgPSS5DQVl4XQZUUSZpazfOWmqYfLyvAQsGUK4GZ0@uv1KDMAYf82wadWPa9Ain3i@jstzuPRk9uckX) Link is to verbose version of code. First input is 0 for right and 1 for left. Explanation:

```
|-DI>-/
```

Print the plane.

```
³↗<→/-ＬηＬη↙¹←<
```

Print the top half of the box (note trailing space).

```
¿Ｎ↷⁴‖Ｔ
```

If the second input is nonzero, reverse the print direction, otherwise reflect the plane and box.

```
⮌⪫η
```

Print the message with extra spacing (note trailing space). The cursor is at the far end of the box from the plane so the message needs to be reversed.

```
‖Ｂ↓
```

Reflect to get the bottom half of the box.

Comment: Verbose version seems to have issues.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Deverbosifier was broken recently; TIO doesn't seem to have the fix yet.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>68</s> 65 bytes

```
“/\<“\/>”y
³K“|-DI>-/---< “ < ”j
LḤ‘”-x⁾//jṭ⁶x11¤Fµ,Ñj¢œs3U⁴¡YÑ⁴¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwxz9GBsgGaNv96hhbiXXoc3eQF6Nrounna6@rq6ujQKQqwAi52Zx@TzcseRRwwwgW7fiUeM@ff2shzvXPmrcVmFoeGiJ26GtOocnZh1adHRysXHoo8YthxZGHp4Ipv///x8Q4Oz@3wAA)

Takes 1 for right, 0 for left.

*-3 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan* (*grr* I always forget `AB+` does the same as `B+@A`)

Comment: `³K“|-DI>-/---< “ < ”j` saves a byte; `LḤ‘”-x⁾//jṭ⁶x11¤Fµ,Ñj¢œs3U⁴¡YÑ⁴¡` saves another 2 in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>55</s> <s>47</s> 43 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
└"┐ξA∫`Ν┌r4≥‘┘¹§,{e⌡↔@¹"╝′‰‘┼}"-<-/ \”┼e?±↔
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTE0JTIyJXUyNTEwJXUwM0JFQSV1MjIyQiU2MCV1MDM5RCV1MjUwQ3I0JXUyMjY1JXUyMDE4JXUyNTE4JUI5JUE3JTJDJTdCZSV1MjMyMSV1MjE5NEAlQjklMjIldTI1NUQldTIwMzIldTIwMzAldTIwMTgldTI1M0MlN0QlMjItJTNDLS8lMjAlNUMldTIwMUQldTI1M0NlJTNGJUIxJXUyMTk0,inputs=L0hhcHB5JTIwJTI4YmlydGhkYXklMjklMEEx)

0 for left and 1 for right

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 56 bytes

<sup>-8 bytes thanks to [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman) and [Erik the Outgolfer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)</sup>

```
≔⪫Ｓ θ≔⁺Ｌθ²η× ¹¹/η/⸿|-DI>-/³<× η<‖Ｂ↓ＦＮ«‖ＴＭ⁺η³→≔⮌θθ»↑↑Ｍη←θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RHq1a/37NZ4dwOELtx1/s9a87tOLTp3PbD0xUO7Ty0U//cdv1HO/bX6Lp42unqH9psAxQ/t93mUcO093sWPWqb/H7Psvd71h1aDRbY8n7PWqAZ57Yf2vyobRLIwHU953YAzdv9qG0iEAGlz21/1Dbh3I7//wMCnN25DAE)

Fixing the cases [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima) mentioned took quite a toll on the byte count. [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RHq1a/37NZ4dyOw9MVDu08tFP/UeOu93vWnNtxaJP@ox37a3RdPO109Q9ttgEqUbB51DDt/Z5Fj9omv9@z7P2edWDulv//AwKc3bkMAQ) if we are allowed to reverse characters like `<` and `/`.

Comment: In python, `' '.join(s)` works. Surely that can be used in Charcoal?

Comment: @totallyhuman `Join` works on strings too.

Comment: Umm, I think it was totallyhuman who actually suggested that.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, I misinterpreted @totallyhuman's suggestion as making a call to Python's `' '.join` in Charcoal. I'll credit both of you.

Comment: You've broken the ast processor...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>137</s> <s>136</s> 133 bytes

```python
lambda s,d:'{0}/{1}-/\n|-DI{3}-{4}---{5} {2} {5} \n{0}\\-{1}\\'.format(' '*11,'--'*len(s),' '.join(s),*list('></\\<>')[d::2])[::-d|1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxDoIwFEV3voLtUdIHFHVpkEUT48bOY8BUIgYKARZT@u3YEBOHm3tz7hk/y2vQ6dacaevq/qFqf@ZKgklsbITFmPSK17s5WDRHi4jmZH2Turgm7TQidCIRRM0w9fUSgA@hEBwQIeyeOpgZdyh6D@2@w66dnZRnMVGWAyuVlGnFSilRraLaxqnVi98EUBSXG3DBPG9HQBp@8/8mbPsC)

`1` for right and `0` for left

Comment: [135 bytes (-1 byte)](https://tio.run/##RYqxDoIwFEV3vqLbo6QPKOpCkEUT48ZOGTCViIFCgMWUfnutaOJwc27uPeNreQwqsc1R2K7ub7ImM5Mp6NhEmhuMhFrxfNWJQb0ziKj3huiDi6NQThMCnSgEhM0w9fXiA4GAcwaIEHR35c@UQZ5BKSsGkfO2kuVfEgifQ/uRaJmmKFde2XFq1UIaH4ridAHGqedtEwgFv/p/Y2rf) by replacing `1-2*d` with `-d|1` (negate `d` xor `1`).

Comment: Typo, it's not xor, it's bitwise or, in fact.

Comment: [134 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYqxDoIwFEV3v4LtUdIHtOrSIIsmxo2dx4BBIgYKARZT@@21ISYON/fm3DO91@eopWtP5Pp6uDd1sPBGgUltYoTFhPQHLzezt2gOFhHN0QZG@vgm7TUi9CIRxO04D/UaQgCREBwQIeofOlwY9yh@jd22o75bvJRnCVGWAysbpWTFSqUEyqip3DR3eg3aEIrifAUu2G63ISANv/l/U@a@ "Python 2 – Try It Online") with a little trick: `*list('></\\<>')[d::2]`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 175 bytes

```php
[,$d,$s]=$argv;$f=str_repeat("--",strlen($s));$r="\-$f\           
 ".join(" ",str_split("><"[$d].$s)).($d?" <---/->":" >---\-<")."ID-|
/-$f/           ";echo$d?strrev($r):$r;
```

Run with `-nr`, first argument = `0` for facing right or `1` for left and second argument=text
or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3174051f2e9771d3fa2ffc68410987d2d3d6037c).

Answer (score 1):

## [Corea](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Corea), 51 bytes

```
"u *:>ip.j:l)X-'/S:>"
|-DI>-/---< V< 
"h}>>`tHL`idF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84vSk38/1@pVEHLyi6zQC/LKkczQlddP9jKTomrRtfF005XX1dX10YhzEaBSymj1s4uocTDJyEzxe3//4AAZ3cuQwA)

### Explanation

The program is composed of a few parts:

### 1: Initialization

```
"u *:>ip.j:l)X-'/S:>"
"..................."   execute the inside as code
 u                      repeat
   *                    a space, 11 times
    :                   duplicate this string
     >                  write this string to the content field
      i                 take a line of input
       p                push a space
        .j              insert that space after every character
          :l)           get (length(str) + 1)
             X-         repeat a hyphen that many times
               '/       push the "/" character
                 S      surround that string with the above character
                  :>    duplicate and write that string to the content field
```

### 2: raw text

The following text is outputted to the content field:

```
|-DI>-/---< V<
```

### 3: postamble

```
"h}>>`tHL`idF
"               execute until the end of the file
 h              mirror the previous string horizontally
  }             move the modified input string to the front of the stack
   >>           write the top two strings to the content field
     `   `id    do the inside `i`nput times
      tH        reflect the content field horizontally and vertically
        L       reverse the input string
            F   save the input string in a field (default: V)
                this replaces all Vs in the code with the input string
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 126 bytes

**124 bytes code + 2 for `-pl`.**

```perl
s/./$& /g;$_=($q=$"x11 .'/-'.s/./-/gr."/
")."|-DI>-/---< $_<
".$q=~y|\\/|/\\|r;<>&&(y|<>|><|,$_=reverse,s/>/ >/,s|-/-|-\\-|)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcy9CoMwFEDh3adIQ/AHvLk6OBkzlA7t0DcIiFCxgtQ0kdLApY/e1M6H79jRLU2MHiWKlOHUir7LxbMT/F3XTGYImfxHwMlJjgkvJCc4XTQgACgmepVwuYNPIGOQ0BhyrdJpmgdSmrSicl@68TU6P5YeNTKNpafdExgDVMR4HqwN7Di77X4bwiGpv6vd5vXhI1wbWdVVBLv8AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 210 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input input as string from [A1] and int from range [B1] where 1 indicates that the plane is on the left and 0 indicates that the plane is on the right.

```vb
=If(B1,"           /","\")&Rept("-",2*Len(A1)+1)&If(B1,"/
","\
")&If(B1,"|-DI>-/---< "," > ")&RegexReplace(A1,"(.)","$1 ")&If(B1,"<
",">---\-<ID-|
")&If(B1,"           \","/")&Rept("-",2*Len(A1)+1)&If(B1,"\","/
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 198 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as string from `[A1]` and int from range `[B1]` where `1` indicates that the plane is on the left and `0` indicates that the plane is on the right.

```vb
b=[B1]:a=StrConv(IIf(b,[A1],StrReverse([A1])),64):j=[Rept("-",2*Len(A1)+1)]:k="/"&j &"/":l="\"&j &"\":s=Space(11):?IIf(b,s &k,l):?IIf(b,"|-DI>-/---< "," > ")a;IIf(b,"<",">---\-<ID-|"):?IIf(b,s &l,k)
```